# string builder vs string

Tags: .net, stringbuilder

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to use StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529999/when-to-use-stringbuilder)
>   [string is immutable and stringbuilder is mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665499/string-is-immutable-and-stringbuilder-is-mutable)

what is diffrent of string and string builder ?
where do we use string builder ?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that a StringBuilder is mutable (meaning that it can be modified), whereas a string is immutable (meaning that once it is constructed it cannot be modified).

This difference is important for example if you are trying to create a large string from lots of smaller strings. If you use a StringBuilder you append the strings without creating a new object, giving O(n) performance. If you use strings you create lots of intermediate strings which are immediately discarded, but all the extra copying means that it becomes an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation.

Example code showing the usage of each for contructing a large string from many smaller strings:

**String**

```
string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    s += "foo";
}
```

**StringBuilder**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    sb.Append("foo");
}
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from string being immutable and stringbuilder being mutable, you should use a string builder when you are going to be doing a lot of string concatenation, as that is a very expensive operation, especially when contained in a loop.