# C# Extension Methods - return calling object

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm new to Extension Methods and exploring what they can do.

Is it possible for the calling object to be assigned the output without a specific assignment?

Here is a simple example to explain:

```
public static string ExtensionTest(this string input)
{
    return input + " Extended!";
}
```

In the following examples ...

```
var foo = "Hello World!";

var foo2 = foo.ExtensionTest(); // foo2 = "Hello World! Extended!"

foo.ExtensionTest(); // foo = "Hello World!"

foo = foo.ExtensionTest(); // foo = "Hello World! Extended!"
```

... is there any way to get `foo.ExtensionTest()` to result in `"Hello World! Extended!"` without specifically assigning `foo = foo.ExtensionTest()`

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `this ref` modifier on a static method where the call-site looks like `foo.Extension();`. Unfortunately, the language doesn't have this feature at the moment. Perhaps something to recommend to the language designers? :) Personally, I wouldn't want it.

Comment: @Ani: Haha, no! Oh man, can you imagine the *abuse* that would ensue? `string bar = foo; foo.DoSomething(); Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(bar, foo));` ... (output: `False`, developer: *WHAAAT?!?*)

Comment: @Dan Tao: Exactly. All your refs are belong to static methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, but the reason that will not work has to do with the immutability of strings, and nothing to do with extension methods.

If instead you had a class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

And an extension method:

```
public static void DoIt(this SomeClass someClass)
{
    someClass.Value++;
}
```

Would have the effect of:

```
var someClass = new SomeClass{ Value = 1 };
someClass.DoIt();

Console.WriteLine(someClass.Value); //prints "2"
```

Comment: I actually want to do this on XmlNodes and XmlDocuments - this was a simpler (I thought!) example for the general question.

Answer (score 6):

The closest you could get to this (which would be weird) would be to accept an `out` parameter and use that as the return value:

```
public static void ExtensionTest(this string input, out string output)
{
    output = input + " Extended!";
}
```

Example:

```
string foo = "Hello World!";
foo.ExtensionTest(out foo);
```

The funny thing about that is, while it more closely *resembles* what you're asking about, it's actually slightly more to type.

To be clear: I *don't* recommend this, unless it's **really** important to you to make this sort of method call. The probability of another developer uttering "WTF?" upon seeing it has got to be something like 100%.

Comment: I like this! It is a good work-around according to the posted question. good job +1

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing is due to strings being immutable.

In any case, you will *have* to do some sort of assignment if you want the object to change.

Comment: I actually want to do this on XmlNodes and XmlDocuments - this was a simpler (I thought!) example for the general question.

Answer (score 4):

The 'this' parameter is passed by value, not by reference. So no, you can't modify the variable in the calling program that is aliased by 'this' in your extension method.

Answer (score 1):

No. Strings in .NET are immutable. All public String methods return new instance of String too.

Answer (score 1):

To assign the new value to your variable inside the extension method, you'd need a ref modifyer on the parameter, which the C# compiler does not permit on extension methods (and it would be a bad idea anyway). It's better to make it clear you're changing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the faster StringBuilder for mutable strings and as pointed out the [`ref` or `out` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out/12571562#12571562).  StringBuilder is basically an improved linked-list for strings.
 Immutable strings were a design decision to allow close behavior to the C language and many other languages.

```
string str = "foo";

str  += "bar"; // str will be free for garbage collection, 
//creating a new string object.
//Note: not entirely true in later C# versions.

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuild();
sb.Append("foo");
sb.Append("bar"); // appends object references to a linked list.
```

**See also:**

- [string is immutable and stringbuilder is mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665499/string-is-immutable-and-stringbuilder-is-mutable)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list