# Mutability of string when string doesn't change in C#

Tags: c#, string, immutability, stringbuilder, mutable

If the string operation doesn't change the value of string, will that end up in creation of a new instance?

For example,

```
string str = "foo";
str += "";
```

I know the difference between string and StringBuilder in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a new instance will be created only when the string operation changes the value in the string variable.

It can be proved using the [ObjectIDGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It's worth reading [this complete article](https://medium.com/@CodAffection/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c-54098af9c354) for proof.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace StringVsStringBuilder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjectIDGenerator idGenerator = new ObjectIDGenerator();
            bool blStatus = new bool();
            // blStatus indicates whether the instance is new or not
            string str = "Fashion Fades,Style Remains Same";
            Console.WriteLine("Initial state");
            Console.WriteLine("str = {0}", str);
            Console.WriteLine("Instance id: {0}", idGenerator.GetId(str, out blStatus));
            Console.WriteLine("This is new instance: {0}", blStatus);
            // A series of operations that won't change value of str
            str += "";

            // Try to replace character 'x' which is not present in str so no change
            str = str.Replace('x', 'Q');

            // Trim removes whitespaces from both ends so no change
            str = str.Trim();
            str = str.Trim();
            Console.WriteLine("\nFinal state");
            Console.WriteLine("str = {0}", str);
            Console.WriteLine("Instance id: {0}", idGenerator.GetId(str, out blStatus));
            Console.WriteLine("This is new instance: {0}", blStatus);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. You can simply test it using `object.ReferenceEquals()` as follows:

```
        string s = "test";
        string q = s;
        s += "";
        bool eq1 = object.ReferenceEquals(s, q); //--> References are equal
        s += "1";
        bool eq2 = object.ReferenceEquals(s, q); //--> References are not equal any more
```

Answer (score 2):

String.Concat(string,string), which is normally what the compiler turns string 'addition' into, checks if one of the arguments is null or empty, and returns the non-NullOrEmpty argument. So in your example, it will simply return str, and no object is created.

In reality though, the [compiler may optimize away your entire operation](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/), noticing that you're just concatenating an empty string. A better test would be where both values are variables, and one happens to contain an empty string.