# C# How StringBuilder is mutable?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I was trying to find out a post which should explain how exactly append function works for StringBuilder.

I got across through this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685639/3239305)

Now, String is immutable. I get this.

But, StringBuilder is also initializing a new temporary character array whenever we try to append something to it.

Comment: You can read the code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs). Long story short: StringBuilder is backed by a char array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string is immutable and stringbuilder is mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665499/string-is-immutable-and-stringbuilder-is-mutable)

Comment: they are two different objects. String is immutable. StringBuilder is not. The fact that StringBuilder starts with String doesnot necessarily mean it has to be immutable too. :)

Comment: Strings are inmutable, so every time you modify a string a new object is created and written to memory, even if you change only one letter. StringBuilder provides a buffer (I think by default is 64 Bytes) and you can add new strings, modify etc... and they are stored in the same block of memory until the buffer is full and a new block is created.

Comment: "StringBuilder is also initializing a new temporary character array whenever we try to append something to it" why do you think that? It uses multiple char arrays to avoid large object heap, but it does not create new one every time you append, only if there is not enough space in current array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutable doesn't mean that it can't create new stuff. Mutable just means that its state can change after the constructor returns.

For example, this is mutable, even though `string` is immutable:

```
class Foo {
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public void FooMethod() {
        Bar = new string('!', 10);
    }
}
```

Because we can change the state of it by setting `Bar` or calling `FooMethod`:

```
 someFoo.FooMethod();
```

Yes, I am creating a new `string` here in the `FooMethod`, but that does not matter. What does matter is that `Bar` now has a new value! The state of `someFoo` changed.

We say `StringBuilder` is mutable because its state can change, without creating a new `StringBuilder`. As you have looked up, `StringBuilder` stores a char array. Each time you append something, that char array changes to something else, but no new `StringBuilder`s are created. This is solid proof that `StringBuilder` is mutable.

Comment: You could also mention why StringBuilder is mutable: The String object is immutable. Every time you use one of the methods in the String class, you create a new string object in memory, which requires a new allocation of space for that new object. In situations where you need to perform repeated modifications to a string, the overhead associated with creating a new String object can be costly. The StringBuilder class can be used when you want to modify a string without creating a new object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

The `*Builder` pattern is a common pattern for creating objects, especially immutable objects, using a richer interface than simply passing in a bunch of data in the constructor. The relation between class `X` and a class `XBuilder` will usually be an immutable `X` and an `XBuilder` that can *build* an X. `XBuilder` doesn't need to be immutable, because it's not the actual data type you eventually need, it's just a temporary scaffold for constructing `X`.

In other words, `StringBuilder` isn't a mutable version of `string`. It's a class, a unit of functionality, that exists to help you create an immutable `string`. You instantiate a `StringBuilder`, use its various `Append` methods to define what should be in the final string (which doesn't, logically, exist yet), and then, when you're done, call `myStringBuilder.ToString()` (which, I think, should have been called `BuildString()`), to get the actual string you wanted.