# Most efficent way of joining strings

Tags: c#, performance, string

I need to concatenate a lot of strings alltogether and put a comma between any of them.
I have a list of strings

```
"123123123213"
"1232113213213"
"123213123"
```

and I want to get

```
"123123123213,1232113213213,123213123"
```

I was wondering what is the best way to achieve that.

I could do this like this:

```
private List<string> stringList = new List<string> { 
    // a lot of strings in here
    "1234567890", "34343434", "4343434" }; 

string outcome = string.Join(",", stringList.ToArray());
```

Or maybe:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
stringList.ForEach(val => {
    builder.Append(val);
    builder.Append(",");
});

string outcome = builder.ToString();
```

Which way is better? Do you know better ways to concatenate strings?

Comment: Related or maybe duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3102806/340760

Comment: Why don't you test the performance yourself?

Comment: You didn't specify what means best. I've added the [performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag to your question.

Answer (score 6):

As [@Ekkehard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851291/most-efficent-way-of-joining-strings/5851344#5851344) said, use the [string.Join](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi).

However, you do not need the `ToArray()` because `string.Join` has an overload for `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> 
    { "1234567890", "34343434", "4343434" }; 

string outcome = string.Join(",", stringList);
```

**EDIT**

As [@Kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi) said, this will work only C# 4.0.  In 3.5 I would do.

```
var s = new StringBuilder(stringList.Count * 8);
foreach (var item in stringList)
{
   s.Append(item);
   s.Append(',');
}
s.Length -= 1;
string outcome = stringList.ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this is new in .Net 4, 3.5 still needs an array.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `string.Join()` because:

a) it's much more readable, maintainable and easy on the eyes.

b) it uses a `StringBuilder` internally already, so it's very efficient ( you can confirm yourself using Reflector).

**Edit:**

`string.Join()` uses a `StringBuilder` for the general case of an `IEnumerable<T>` input. If you already have an array on the other hand it uses some voodoo magic (including `FastAllocateString()` and         `UnSafeCharBuffer`) to be even faster.

Comment: FYI, `string.Join(string, string[])` *does not* use `StringBuilder`, but `UnSafeCharBuffer`.

Comment: @svick: Yes just was in the process of editing that in after making that observation as well- it's vodoo magic indeed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use Join, because it doesn't add a trailing ",".

Answer (score 1):

There's a benchmark on [this page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join-string) that seems to show that `string.Join` performs better than `StringBuilder` on a small array in a lot of iterations. you should probably benchmark for larger arrays also. As I'm posting this I see that BrokenGlass answered that `StringBuilder` is used internally in `string.Join` so you can expect it to be faster I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution adds an extra `,` at the end. Take a look at [Eric Lippert`s blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/13/restating-the-problem.aspx)

I would recommend fixing your second solution. A StringBuilder would be definitely faster, as you avoid coping the list contents to a new array.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
string separator = "";
stringList.ForEach(
    val =>
    {
        builder.Append(separator).Append(val);
        separator = ",";
    });
string outcome = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder is a very efficient way and would be recommended here.

Comment: Except `string.Join()` can be even more effective (at least in the case, when you give it `string[]`, otherwise is uses `StringBuilder` itself).

Comment: svick you have given a -1 to somebody that said something more clever than you. And however the asker needs it for a list of strings not for an array.

Comment: @Marino, how is using `StringBuilder` more clever than using `string.Join()`? The latter is much more clearer, less error prone (you don't have to write your own code) and possibly faster.

Comment: Gosh, it is just an alternative.

Comment: To use string.join you have to take the list and first make an array. That may not be the most efficient way, especially if you have a lot of little strings.

Answer (score 0):

This adhoc implementation I tried with the StrignBuilder is faster than String.Join.
More than that String.Join is a MEMORY HOG.
I tried with 20000000 strings and String.Join always gives OutOfMemory, when my implementation finishes.
On your machine It may be even on less strings if you have less than 8Gb of memory.
Comment one of the implementations to  test.
This holds true unless you use a fixed string[] array. String.Join is good there.

```
   public static void Main(string[] Args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

          List<string> strings = new List<string>() {};
        for (double d = 0; d < 8000000; d++) {
            strings.Add(d.ToString());
        }

        TimeSpan upTime;
        TimeSpan newupTime;
        using (var pc = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strings.Count);
            int i;

            pc.NextValue();    //The first call returns 0, so call this twice
            upTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pc.NextValue());

            for (i = 0; i < strings.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(strings[i]);
                sb.Append(",");
            }
            sb.Append(strings[i]);

            newupTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pc.NextValue());
            sb = null;
            Console.WriteLine("SB " + (newupTime - upTime).TotalMilliseconds);
        }

        using (var pc = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
        {

            pc.NextValue();
            upTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pc.NextValue());

            string s = string.Join(",", strings);

            newupTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pc.NextValue());
            Console.WriteLine("JOIN " + (newupTime - upTime).TotalMilliseconds);
        }


    }
SB 406
JOIN 484
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the following test I've made, **Join is 3x faster faster** on large arrays:

The `Text.txt` file contains the value `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` on 38400 lines:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var strings = File.ReadAllLines("Text.txt");

      Stopwatch sw;

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
      {
        sb.AppendLine(strings[i]);
      }
      sw.Stop();
      TimeSpan sbTime = sw.Elapsed;

      sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
     var output = string.Join(",", strings);
     sw.Stop();

     TimeSpan joinTime = sw.Elapsed;   

    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
00:00:00.0098754
00:00:00.0032922
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.Join](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/StringBuilder_vs_String.aspx) is the fastest if you have a fixed number of strings to join. The deeper reason is that String.Join does loop over the array and allocates the final string buffer with the right size because it does in the first pass add the string length of all strings together. You can get similar results when you play around with StringBuilder and its capacity. The golden rule is to spare memory allocations at the cost of looping over the array two times. Which approach is faster depends on how many items you have in your list and how big the resultint string will get.

Yours,
  Alois Kraus

Answer (score 0):

Test code:

```
public static void Performance(Action fn)
{
    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    {
        fn();
    }

    timer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} Time: {1}ms ({2})", fn.ToString(), timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, timer.ElapsedTicks);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stringList = new List<string>() {
        "123123123213",
        "1232113213213",
        "123213123"
    };

    string outcome = String.Empty;
    Performance(() =>
    {
        outcome = string.Join(",", stringList);
    });

    Console.WriteLine(outcome);

    Performance(() =>
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        stringList.ForEach
            (
                val =>
                {
                    builder.Append(val);
                    builder.Append(",");
                }
            );
        outcome = builder.ToString();
        outcome = outcome.Substring(0, outcome.Length - 1);
    });

    Console.WriteLine(outcome);

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Result 1. `String.Join` - 2. `StringBuilder + SubString`. `####ms (ticks)`

[image: result]

In this case `String.Join` is faster, but if you are ok with a trailing `,` then

[image: string builder]

`StringBuilder` is slightly faster (with a trailing `,`).

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to be cool and run on *Heavy Fuel* use Aggregate

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "1234567890", "34343434", "4343434" };

Console.WriteLine( stringList.Aggregate( ( current, next ) => string.Format( "{0}, {1}", current, next ) ) );

// Outputs:   1234567890, 34343434, 4343434
```