# How Convert all to one string?

Tags: c#, string

I need to convert this line in one string, because my method "DisplayMessage" only accept 1 argument, so how can I do this?

```
_userOptions.DisplayMessage("\nFile Generated: " +
     BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)) + 
     "\nTime Elapsed:  {0} minute(s) {1} second(s)",
     timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds / 10 + "\n");
```

Comment: Use Environment.NewLine instead of \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string indicates that you want to call the [static `Format` method on the `String` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx), like so:

```
_userOptions.DisplayMessage(string.Format(
    "\nFile Generated: {0}\nTime Elapsed:  {1} minute(s) {2} second(s)\n",
    BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)),
    timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds / 10));
```

However, this will give you a problem, as you have more parameters than you have placeholders in the string.

Additionally, given comments regarding the use of "\n" as a new line delimiter, unless you have a specific need for that specific format (and it does not seem that you do, you aren't indicating you are writing to a file, or to something where the data is going to an external system), it's better to use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx), which you can use like so (note, this still does not address the fact you have more parameters than you do placeholders:

```
_userOptions.DisplayMessage(string.Format(
    "{0}File Generated: {1}{0}Time Elapsed:  {2} minute(s) {3} second(s){0}",
    Environment.NewLine,
    BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)),
    timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds / 10));
```

Comment: are you sure that your parenthesis are right? Check... :) I think `+"\n"` goes into string declaration, not in params...

Comment: @Marco: Was already editing for that when you commented, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your DisplayMessage method does not allow for the string format.  Try putting this entire content (everything inside the parenthesis of `DisplayMessage`) inside a `String.Format()` method.  That will make it one string and still allow for the multiple parameters you are passing.

Comment: same answer at same time. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string s= String.Format(
    "\nFile Generated: " +
    BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)) + 
    "\nTime Elapsed:  {0} minute(s) {1} second(s) {2} msec(s)\n",
    timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds / 10);
_userOptions.DisplayMessage(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var msg = String.Format("\nFile Generated: {0}\nTime Elapsed: {1} minute(s) {2} second(s)\n", BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)), timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);

_userOptions.DisplayMessage(msg);
```

This should do it...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to [use `String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx). This takes a string and replace `{#}` by the argument index.

Example:

```
String.Format("Hi {0}, welcome to Stack Overflow!", "ale");
```

You might want to have a look at [`How should I concatenate strings?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102806/340760)

Answer (score 1):

This is more elegant in my opinion:

```
string message = string.Format("{0}File Generated: {1}{0}Time Elapsed:  {2} minute(s) {3} second(s) {4} milliseconds{0}", 
    "\n", BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)), timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds / 10);
_userOptions.DisplayMessage(message);
```

Using `Format` there's no need to use any `+` operator on the strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("File Generated: ");
        sb.Append(BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)));
        sb.Append("\n");
        sb.Append("Time Elapsed: ");
        sb.Append(timeSpan.Minutes);
        sb.Append(" minute(s)");
        sb.Append(timeSpan.Seconds);
        sb.Append(" second(s)");
        sb.Append();
        _userOptions.DisplayMessage(sb.ToString());
```

but i think, you have some bug: you have 2 parameters but actually is 3

Answer (score 0):

Find below.

```
string str = String.Format("\n" + "File Generated: " + BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)) + "\n" + "Time Elapsed: " + " {0} minute(s)" + " {1} second(s)", timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds / 10 + "\n");

_userOptions.DiplayMessage(str);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of {0} and {1}, just use your arguments directly:

```
_userOptions.DisplayMessage("\n" + "File Generated: " + BinaryWriter.GetBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)) + "\n" + "Time Elapsed:" + timeSpan.Minutes + "minute(s)" + timeSpan.Seconds + "second(s)" + timeSpan.Milliseconds / 10 + "\n");
```

Comment: that's not a good way to write code ;)
If you need to change a param you have to search in the string and modify... Params are much better IMHO :)

Comment: @Marco: Agreed, I was just giving the simpelest, most straight-forward solution