# Where is my XDeclaration?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

For some reason the following code produces XML that does not contain a declaration:

```
        XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("project",
                new XAttribute("number", project.ProjectNumber),
                new XElement("store",
                    new XAttribute("number", project.StoreNumber)
                ),

                // User Element
                new XElement("user", 
                    new XAttribute("owner-id", project.OwnerID ?? 0),
                    new XElement("email", new XCData(project.OwnerEmail ?? "")),
                    new XElement("project-name", new XCData(project.ProjectName ?? ""))
                ),

                // Nested Project Element
                new XElement("nested-project", 
                    new XAttribute("version", new Version(1, 0)),
                    new XElement("project", 
                        new XAttribute("version", new Version(1, 0)),
                        xProjectItems = new XElement("project-items")
                    ),
                    new XElement("price-per-part", project.PricePerPart),
                    new XElement("sheet-quantity", project.SheetQuantity),
                    new XElement("edge-length", project.EdgeLength),
                    new XElement("price", project.Price),
                    new XElement("status", project.Status),
                    xMaterialItems = new XElement("alternative-material-items"),
                    xProductItems = new XElement("project-product-items")
                )
            )
        );

        String strXML = xDocument.ToString();
```

It has produced a declaration before.  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The XDeclaration will be available when you use one of the [`XDocument.Save` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save.aspx). For example:

```
var doc = new XDocument (
            new XDeclaration ("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement ("test", "data")
        );

string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "temp.xml");
doc.Save(path);
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

Alternately you could use this approach:

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(sw);
string result = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**EDIT:** note that some approaches will convert the utf-8 designation to utf-16. If you want to force it to be utf-8 you would have to use this different approach:

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())  
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(mem, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    mem.Flush();
    mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(mem))
    {
        var xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's lame. Not your solution (which is pretty cool-- I didn't realize you could do that with a `StringWriter`).  Its lame that Microsoft would do that. I'm not saving this XML to a file, I'm passing it into a stream. What's the difference between an 'XDocument' and an 'XElement'.  I mean its good that they are alike, but there should be some distinction. And if someone doesn't want the declaration in the string then you could just do: `xMyDocument.Root.ToString();`

Comment: @Jordan I suppose the rationale is that an XDocument represents an entire document, and an XElement is a fragment of XML. Despite that, they're very similar.

Comment: Oh, I know how they are different in general, but in LINQ to XML, an `XDocument` seems to be little more than an `XElement` that cannot be contained.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) does not state explicitly that `xDocument.ToString()` will output the XML declaration, it only says: "Returns the indented XML for this node.".

In my testing, I found that the following methods will output the declaration:

Use `ToString` on the `Declaration` property:

```
string strXML = string.Concat(xDocument.Declaration.ToString(), "\r\n",
                              xDocument.ToString());
```

or use the `Save` method:

```
string strXml;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    xDocument.Save(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        strXml = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I think @Ahmad Mageed's approach with `StringWriter` is the way to go. Same idea but shorter than my `Save` method.

Comment: +1 for the effort. I suppose there is a case for the longer approach, as shown in my edit, when needing to force the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

My answer *(inspired by [the answer by @rsbarro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6270121/1497596))*:

```cs
string xml = xDocument.Declaration.ToString() +
    xDocument.ToString();
```

***- or -***

```cs
string xml = xDocument.Declaration.ToString() +
    xDocument.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

As to why I believe use of the `+` operator is appropriate in this situation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21131/1497596) to the question [What's the best string concatenation method using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21078/1497596).