# Add An XML Declaration To String Of XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have some xml data that looks like..

```
<Root>
<Data>Nack</Data>
<Data>Nelly</Data>
</Root>
```

I want to add `"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"`  to this string. Then preserve the xml as a string.

I attempted a few things..

This breaks and loses the original xml string

```
myOriginalXml="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"  + myOriginalXml;
```

This doesnt do anything, just keeps the original xml data with no declaration attached.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(myOriginalXml);
                XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8","no");
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
                doc.WriteTo(tx);
                string xmlString = sw.ToString();
```

This is also not seeming to have any effect..

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(myOriginalXml);
                XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no");
                MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
                doc.Save(xmlStream);
                xmlStream.Flush();
                xmlStream.Position = 0;
                doc.Load(xmlStream);
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
                doc.WriteTo(tx);
                string xmlString = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is my XDeclaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269881/where-is-my-xdeclaration)

Comment: Maybe my code is wrong but saving the document isnt working either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [xmlwritersettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhksz5c0.aspx) to achieve greater control over saving. The [XmlWriter.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162620.aspx) accepts that setting (instead of the default contructor)

```
    var myOriginalXml = @"<Root>
                            <Data>Nack</Data>
                            <Data>Nelly</Data>
                          </Root>";
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(myOriginalXml);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var tx = XmlWriter.Create(ms, 
                new XmlWriterSettings { 
                             OmitXmlDeclaration = false, 
                             ConformanceLevel= ConformanceLevel.Document,
                             Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8 });
    doc.Save(tx);
    var xmlString = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

Comment: The encoding is utf-16 I need utf-8 is that an easy fix to this code?

Comment: I added this..Encoding=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 but the encoding stayed utf-16

Comment: +1. @NickLaMarca - check suggested duplicate - it contain all information you need (you need writer with encoding you want, `StringWriter` obviously is UTF-16 only).

Comment: This code works all the way but the UTF part. How can this code be modified to use memory stream instead of stream writer?

Comment: @NickLaMarca I had to get rid of the StringWriter and have a memorystream instead. It now generates an xml declaration with an UTF-8 encoding in it...