# Most efficient way to concatenate string?

Tags: c#, lambda, concatenation

What is the best way to concatenate string to receive `ukr:'Ukraine';rus:'Russia';fr:'France'` result?

```
public class Country
{
    public int IdCountry { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

var lst = new List<Country>();
lst.Add(new Country(){IdCountry = 1, Code = "ukr", Title = "Ukraine"});
lst.Add(new Country() { IdCountry = 2, Code = "rus", Title = "Russia" });
lst.Add(new Country() { IdCountry = 3, Code = "fr", Title = "France" });
string tst = ????
```

Comment: Is your target pattern really `Code:'Title';` followed by `Code:'Title',` ?  Notice the first pair ends in a semicolon, the second pair ends in a comma.  Is this intentional?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best string concatenation method using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c)

Comment: shanabus, pattern correcred, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think something like this would be fairly readable:

```
string tst = string.Join(";", lst.Select(x=> string.Format("{0}:'{1}'", x.Code, x.Title)));
```

`string.Join()` is using a `StringBuilder` under the hood so this should not be creating unnecessary strings while assembling the result.

Since the parameter to `string.Join()` is just an `IEnumerable` (.NET 4 required for this overload) you can also split this out into two lines to further improve readability (in my opinion) without impacting performance:

```
var countryCodes = lst.Select(x=> string.Format("{0}:'{1}'", x.Code, x.Title));
string test = string.Join(";", countryCodes);
```

Comment: Consider replacing string.Format("...") with string.Concat(x.Code, ":'", x.Title, "'").

Comment: @Jason - I don't agree: `string.Format` uses a `StringBuilder` internally so I don't see the performance gain using `string.Concat()` **and** it is much less readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can override ToString method within Country class to return `string.format("{0}:'{1}'", Code, Title)` and use string.join to join that list members.

Comment: What about the semi colon between the elements!

Comment: That would go within the `string.Join`, as demonstrated in BrokenGlass’s answer. The code then becomes really elegant: `string.Join(";", lst)`. The `Join` method would take care of calling `ToString` on each element in the sequence.

Answer (score -1):

the `Enumerable.Aggregate` method is pretty good.

```
var tst = lst.Aggregate((base, current) => 
                  base + ";" + String.Format("{0}:'{1}'", current.Code, current.Title));
```

Answer (score -1):

In `C# 6.0` you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/csharp-six#String-Interpolation) in order to display formatted dates.

```
string tst = lst.Aggregate((base, current) => 
    $"{base};{current.Code}:'{current.Title}'");
```

Answer (score -2):

Slightly efficient way as `LINQ` tends often to be less efficient then simple `foreach` or `for` (in this case) loop.

All depends on what *exactly* you mean, by saying "most efficient way".

Extension method:

```
public static string ContriesToString(this List<Country> list)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<list.Count;i++)
       result.Add(string.Format("{0}:'{1}';", list[i].Code, list[i].Title));

    result.ToString();
}
```

use:

```
var lst = new List<Country>();
lst.Add(new Country(){IdCountry = 1, Code = "ukr", Title = "Ukraine"});
lst.Add(new Country() { IdCountry = 2, Code = "rus", Title = "Russia" });
lst.Add(new Country() { IdCountry = 3, Code = "fr", Title = "France" });
string tst = lst.ContriesToString();
```

Comment: That would deliver ukr:Ukrainerus:Russiafr:France, was that intended?

Comment: @Lloyd: corrected, by the way the code was provided not for copy-paste, but for idea exploration.