# how to increase the value of an integer in a string

Tags: c#, winforms, string, substring

Ok I currently have this code

```
        public int i = 0; //this is outside of the private void button1_click
        string str = txtEmail.Text;
        int pos = str.LastIndexOf("@");
        string str2 = str.Substring(pos);
        string str3 = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("@"));
        txtEmail.Text = str3 + i++ + str2;
```

it splits the email into 2 string then combines them with an integer between them, But I want it to change the integer. But that code just makes it lets saying the text becomes awesome1@email.com when i press the button to increase the 1 to a 2 it just does this instead. awesome12@email.com and so on. how do i get it to just add 1 to the 1 and not put a 2 next to the 1?

Comment: I think you need to show us the loop (I suspect) you're using, if Jon's answer is not what you're looking for.

Comment: what is variable i, and where is initialized ?

Comment: variable i = 0 currently and is located outside of the button_click event it is a public integer and @AlexInParis im not using a loop

Comment: You need to keep track of the original string, or at least the last index of the number you inserted in order to accurately replace your int value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following and it looks like it solves your problem.  Change this line of yours:

```
string str = txtEmail.Text;
```

To this:

```
string str = txtEmail.Text.Replace(string.Format("{0}@", i - 1), "@");
```

It sets it up so that your email addresses will be in the form of:

```
awesome1@email.com 
awesome2@email.com 
awesome3@email.com 
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where `i` is coming from in this code but hopefully this will work

```
    string str = txtEmail.Text;
    int pos = str.LastIndexOf("@");
    string str2 = str.Substring(pos);
    string str3 = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("@"));
    txtEmail.Text = str3 + (i++).ToSting() + str2;
```

Comment: doesnt work still just adds on to the string and makes it longer doesnt replace the number with the +1 version of itself

Comment: Agreed although I dont think in this case it will be too much of a memory problem

Comment: Better to use string.Concat, avoid the GC overhead of making a stringbuilder

Comment: Also, this might answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c

Comment: @RickHoving i dont think string builder works that way? cause doing that gave me an error saying that stringbuilder "doesnt have a constructor that contains 3 arguments".

Comment: @IanLundberg yeah I cinda messed up there, look at my answer for the correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String email = "awesome1@email.com";
String[] tokens = email.Split(new char[] { '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
const String allowed = "0123456789";
String part1 = "";
String numberStr = "";
foreach (char c in tokens[0].Reverse())
{
    if (allowed.Contains(c) && part1.Length==0)
    {
        numberStr += c;
    }
    else
    {
        part1 += c;
    }
}
part1 = new String(part1.Reverse().ToArray());
int number = int.Parse(new String(numberStr.Reverse().ToArray()));
String result = String.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", part1, number++, tokens[1]);
```

Although it looks a little bit cumbersome. Accept a Regex answer if there's one.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
public static string IncNumberBeforeAt(string text)
{
  int lastAt = text.LastIndexOf('@');
  if (lastAt != -1)
  {
    int pos = lastAt - 1;
    string num = "";
    while (text[pos] >= '0' && text[pos] <= '9')
    {
      num = text[pos] + num;
      pos--;
      if (pos < 0)
        break;          
    }
    int numInc = int.Parse(num) + 1;
    return text.Replace(num.ToString() + "@", numInc.ToString() + "@");
  }
  else
  {
    return text;
  }
}
```

test

```
IncNumberBeforeAt("awesome1@email.com"); // => returns awesome2@email.com
IncNumberBeforeAt("awesome234@email.com"); // => returns awesome235@email.com
IncNumberBeforeAt("email.com"); // => returns email.com
IncNumberBeforeAt("5@email.com"); // => returns 6@email.com
```

Comment: Test `"awesome๐1@email.com"`. `char.IsNumber` (and even `char.IsDigit`) allows to many chars.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep track of your original e-mail address:

e.g.

```
string originalEmail = "test@gmail.com";

var parts = originalEmail.Split('@');

txtEmail.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}@{2}", parts[0], i++, parts[1]);
```

Comment: that still does the same thing aka it doesnt work :/ thanks for trying though

Comment: This will only work if you keep using your original email address, i.e. the one without the integer.