# How to insert a dot between a string

Tags: c#, string

Hello every technical elite, I'm a rookie in C#. This is my first time asking questions on stackoverflow, I'm a Chinese, my english is poor.

I am trying to make my C# application communicate with a digital scale via rs232 by using SerialPort class in .net.

I want insert a dot "."  in a string ,I received the string use:(buf[3].ToString("X2"),the string is a number between 00~99,I  want insert a dot in the number.How to do ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: It it always in the format {one character}{two digits} ? Also I have to say your English is very good.

Comment: [How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx), [What's the best string concatenation method using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c), [Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362(v=vs.100).aspx)...

Comment: Please tell what is input and what is desired output

Comment: Thank you for you helps,I  know how to solve the problem already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string always have 2 characters in it ( Ex :07 / 10 /26), you can get the first and second character by `Substring` function and do a string concatenation with a dot in between.

```
string ss = buf[3].ToString("X2");  
string result= ss.Substring(0, 1) + "." + ss.Substring(1, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!!!!Your answer to help me solve the problem,I have tried four days.Thanks again for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert a string (in this case ".") into another, you can use the [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) method:

```
"99".Insert(1, ".") // results in "9.9"
```

In your case probably:

```
string result = buf[3].ToString("X2").Insert(1, ".");
```

If you just want to append a dot, you can just use the `+` operator:

```
buf[3].ToString("X2") + ".";
```

Comment: Thank you for you helps,I already know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Regex`

```
string ss = buf[3].ToString("X2");
Regex.Replace("(\d)(\d)",ss,"$1.$2");
```

Comment: Thank you for you helps,I already know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
String sringToInstert = buf[3].ToString("X2");
sringToInstert.Insert(0,".");
```

Where 0 is the starting Index (Where you want to put the dot).

And "." is what you want to put.

For starting index 0 the result will be = `.99`

And For starting index 1 the result will be = `9.9`

Comment: Thank you for you helps,I already know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score -4):

string newStr = oldStr[0]+"."+oldStr[1];

Comment: Thank you for you helps,I know how to solve the problem already.