# Most efficient way to return string concatenation from property

Tags: c#, string, concatenation, stringbuilder

Ive read a  few posts on here and the common suggestion is that stringbuilder is the most efficent if joining over three strings.

all variables are other properties.

```
public string Summary
{
  get 
  {
    return Name.Replace("_", " ") + "<strong>[" + Total + " Devices - " + BadCount + " Offline, " + PendingCount + " Pending]</strong>";
  }
}
```

Im joining four, is a simple concatenation suitable or should I ue stringbuilder? Just seems a little overkill.

Comment: You know you're actually concatenating 8 strings right? Every + is a concatenation.

Comment: This looks more suited for `string.Format`

Comment: Can you provide a link for your assertion that the efficiency minimum for a StringBuilder is 3 strings?

Comment: its good to use StringBuilder class...

Comment: Doesn't the C# compiler automatically convert `+` concatenations into `StringBuilder` calls (just like Java does)?

Comment: Jon Skeet: [Concatenating Strings Efficiently](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best string concatenation method using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c -- Sorry cant find original post, but checkign others the numbers vary widely.

Comment: You know you're actually concatenating 8 strings right? -- Of course, silly me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use whatever is most readable in this case. Otherwise it's [premature optimizatio](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)n.

I would use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
String result = String.Format("{0}<strong>[{1} Devices - {2} Offline, {3} Pending]</strong>"
, Name.Replace("_", " ")
, Total
, BadCount
, PendingCount);
return result;
```

Even string concatenation is not that bad since strings are stored in the [**intern pool**](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_String_Theory%E2%80%94String_intern_pool). So if you use a string a second time it's not created but the already available reference is used.

So as rule of thumb:

- If you're concatenating few strings and the code gets hardly to understand,  use `String.Format`
- If you're concatenating few (literal) strings and the code is still readable, use `+`(string concatenation)
- If you're creating strings in a (long) loop with variable strings, use a `StringBuilder`

Comment: Reminds me of this quote: 'You should be more worried about the maintainability and readability of your code than its performance.' The performance difference will be nearly non-existent in the example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ill use string format and accept your answer for the additonal info.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Format`

```
public string Summary
{
  get 
  {
    return String.Format(
        "{0}<strong>[{1} Devices - {2} Offline, {3} Pending </strong>",
        Name.Replace("_", " "), Total, BadCount, PendingCount);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? Apart from tidiness, what performance advantage does it offer over concatenation? (Note this is not disputing your answer, you simply need to do better than say *"use string.Format()"*).

Comment: String.Format uses a `StringBuilder`. It might be neater, but I doubt it's faster.

Comment: Far and away the best approach. String.Format() is optimised, and it also allows you to easily provide localization by putting the format string into the resources. You should always do that anyways, even if you're not going to be localising stuff.

Comment: Excellent answer, this is the approach I will use.