# Padding a zero to the beginning of a string

Tags: c#

I have written a funny looking code that if the first character of string is blank, it will replace that blank space with a "0" and it works but like I said it is funny looking. Is there a nicer way of writing the same thing?

```
    char ch = value[0];
    if (ch == ' ')
    {
        value = value.Trim();
        value = "0" + value;
    }
    return value;
```

Comment: See [What's the best string concatenation method using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c).

Comment: return value[0] == ' ' ? "0" + value.Trim() : value;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
if (value.Length > 0 && value[0] == ' ')
    value = '0' + value.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not checking `value` for nullness - the OP didn't either, but if that's important then add a `value != null &&` to the `if`

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want to achieve, this one is shorter:

```
if(value.StartsWith(" "))
{
  value = string.Format("0{0}", value.Trim());
}
```

Comment: Almost. Will erroneously convert `__foo_` to `0foo` instead of `0_foo_`.

Comment: I just converted the code of DevWannaBe, not the problem explained. It was difficult to know what was the intension of the question.

Comment: you're right, the description doesn't match the OP's sample code. I just thought the caveat is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (value.StartsWith(" "))
{
    value = value.TrimStart(' ');
    value = value.PadLeft(value.Length + 1, '0');
}
```

Assuming `value` is not a null reference. For more information see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match the spaces at the beginning of the string and replace with a zero character:

```
value = Regex.Replace(value, "^ +", "0");
```

If you only want to replace a single space at the beginning of the string, if there happen to be more than one:

```
value = Regex.Replace(value, "^ ", "0");
```

Note: This differs from your original implementation in two ways: It will only remove actual spaces from the beginning of the string, not any white space characters as the `Trim` method does, and it will only remove spaces from the beginning of the string, not also the end of the string, as the `Trim` method does. I assume that those details were not actually the intention of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Trim() and PadLeft():

```
        string value = " 5678";
        value = value.Trim().PadLeft(5, '0');
```

If you had "1", or " 1", or any combination of "1" and spaces, it would end up being "00001".

You just change the 5 to however wide you need your field to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string value = " String with space";
 var firstChar = (byte)value.First();
 if (firstChar == ' ')
 {
    var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(" "));
    value = regex.Replace(value, "0", 1);
 }
 return value;
```

Comment: Is this really better than the original code? Maybe more complex or sophisticated, but better?