# How to use StringBuilder wisely?

Tags: c#, .net, string, memory, stringbuilder

I am little confused about using `StringBuilder` class, first:

> A `string` object concatenation operation always creates a new object from the existing `string` and the new data. A `StringBuilder` object maintains a buffer to accommodate the concatenation of new data. New data is appended to the end of the buffer if room is available; otherwise, a new, larger buffer is allocated, data from the original buffer is copied to the new buffer, then the new data is appended to the new buffer.

But where is the point of creating `StringBuilder` instance to avoid creating new one of `String`? It sounds like trading "one for one".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String foo = "123";
    using (StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(foo)) // also sb isn't disposable, so there will be error
    {
        sb.Append("456");
        foo = sb.ToString();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(foo);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Why I shouldn't just use

```
+=
```

***Edit:*** Ok, I know now how to reuse one instance of `StringBuilder` (still don't know if this is right with code standards), but this isn't worth to use with just one `string`, isn't it?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-performance versus http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat

Comment: @royB What does "string contention uses stringbuilder (str1 + str2) natively" mean? String *concatenation* does in fact *not* use StringBuilder internally.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Modifying *[immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)* structures like [`string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)s must be done by copying the structure, and by that, consuming more memory and slowing the application's run time (also increasing `GC` time, etc...).

`StringBuilder` comes to solve this problem by using the same mutable object for manipulations.

***However:***

when concatenating a `string` in compile time as the following:

```
string myString = "123";
myString += "234";
myString += "345";
```

it will actually compile to something like that:

```
string myString = string.Concat("123", "234", "345");
```

this function is faster than working with `StringBuilder` for the number of `string`s entering the function is known.

so for compile-time-known `string` concatenations you should prefer `string.Concat()`.

as for unknown number of `string` like in the following case:

```
string myString = "123";
if (Console.ReadLine() == "a")
{
    myString += "234";
}
myString += "345";
```

Now the compiler can't use the `string.Concat()` function, however, `StringBuilder` appears to be more efficient in time and memory consumption only when the concatenation is done with 6-7 or more `strings`.

Bad practice usage:

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder("123");
myString.Append("234");
myString.Append("345");
```

Fine practice usage (note that `if` is used):

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder("123");
if (Console.ReadLine() == "a")
{
    myString.Append("234");
}
myString.Append("345");
```

Best practice usage (note that `while` loop is used):

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder("123");
while (Console.ReadLine() == "a")
{
    myString.Append("234"); //Average loop times 4~ or more
}
myString.Append("345");
```

Comment: Aren't your last two examples exactly the same?

Comment: @JaimieKnox note the `while`/`if` and the comment.

Comment: Ah thank you. I must have read that 100 times and still missed it.

Comment: What if you're concatenating in a `for` loop for each item in a list? Will `+=` compile to: `string.concatenate(a,b,...,z)`? If so, do you use a `StringBuilder` if there are ~4 or more items in the list?

Comment: @monster It won't be compiled to `string.Concat` (between all of the `strings` in the `List` at one time) since the compiler can't assume anything about the `strings` in the `List`, therefore, if you assume there will be more than a few concatenations - `StringBuilder` should be used.

Answer (score 13):

A `string` is an *immutable class*. You cannot modify it, only create new `strings`.

So when you write `result += a;` you have three separate `strings` in memory at that point: `a`, the old value of `result` and the new value. Of course this is absolutely fine if you only concatenate a limited number of `strings`. If you do that in a `for` loop iterating over a large collection it can become a problem.

The `StringBuilder` class offers improved performance in these cases. Instead of creating new `strings` to store the result of the concatenation it uses the same object. So if you use `stringBuilder.Append(a);` you never have the equivalent of the "old value of `result`".

---

This memory efficiency comes with a price of course. When only concatenating a small number of `strings` a `StringBuilder` is often less efficienct with regards to speed since it had more overhead compared to the immutable `string` class.

---

One thing to keep in mind is that when you need the intermediate strings then `StringBuilder` can become less efficient since calling `.ToString()` on it creates a new copy of the `string`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because `strings` are immutable. When concatenating a `string` you create a new `string`. So, when you need to concatenate many `strings` you create a lot of `objects`. This doesn't cost much in terms of memory, as each `string` is used once. But it does give extra work for the `GC`.

`StringBuilder` however uses the same `object` each time, but it does so at the expense of ease of use.