# Concatenating List<List<string>> takes a long time

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-concatenation

What I had tried till Now

```
string Value ="";
foreach (List<string> val in L1)
{
   Value = Value + string.Join(",", val) + " // ";
}
```

Where L1 is of datatype `List <List<strings>>`

This Works, But its take almost n half hour to complete
Is there as many fastest and simple way to achieve this.

Comment: What is the size of the list?..

Comment: If you get a large amount of strings this uses a lot of memory and takes a lot of time to process, probably you should change your routine to streaming text and then performing some actions on it

Comment: actually i have List which is equal to List<List<list<list<string>>>>

Comment: When `L1` is a `List<List<string>>`, this loop will throw an `InvalidCastException` because you declare `val` as `List<decimal>`.

Comment: After fixing ^, start using a `StringBuilder` to cut runtime in more than half.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy *List<List<list<list<string>>>>* confuses more though

Comment: I have Geojson Array whose coordinates value has this value List<List<list<list<string>>>>

Comment: Is there any reason why you are getting data from GeoJSON as List<List<list<list<string>>>>? Do you have a code snippet available for that? I feel that there may be something there you could improve upon to achieve desired results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest use [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of concatenations in a loop like that:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (List<string> val in L1)
{
    builder.Append(string.Join(",", val) + " // ");
}
string result = builder.ToString();
```

When concatenating in a loop it needs to copy the string everytime to a new position in memory with the extra allocated memory. `StringBuilder` prevents that.

You can also refer to:

- [How to use StringBuilder wisely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21644658/6400526)
- [How does StringBuilder work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6524240/6400526)
- [How the StringBuilder class is implemented? Does it internally create new string objects each time we append?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3564906/6400526)

Comment: @SimarjeetSinghPanghlia - you are welcome :)