# String - " " + vs " " {}

Tags: c#, string

Is there any difference between writing the following two? The code is for C#

```
String S1 = "The " + Item.Name + " is made of " + Item.Property + " and is at " + Item.Durability + "% durability."
```

against

```
String S2 = "The {0} is made of {1} and is at {2} % durability.", Item.Name, Item.Property, Item.Durability
```

? Assuming that item is populated with, for instance, name of Axe, property of Steel, and durability of 50 as a string.

Comment: I assume there's supposed to be a `string.Format` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is faster, assuming you correctly use it with `String.Format`.

In the first approach, you're internally forcing the system to sequentially build an incrementally larger string, triggering at least a full allocation and internal copy for each of the `+` operations.

In the second, you're letting internally optimized functions first assess all of the parameters, and allocate a single string to contain the entire end result in one go, and copy it in.

Comment: No, it should be optimized to `String.Concat`.

Comment: Thanks for the input both of you. I'd been using + and += for a while now, and I knew += created a new string instance but not that "A " + b + " C " + d would create new instances on each +.

I'll look up concat and try to switch my style to {0}, with string.format (which I did not know was required/recommended for all {0} operations.)

Comment: @Charles: It doesn’t create a new instance on each `+`. Multiple concatenation like that (not in a loop) is optimized to `String.Concat`. Multiple concatenation in a loop should be done with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @false correct, but that's assuming compiler smartness. I don't think it's in the spec that the compiler should do that. Relatively moot point of course given that MS writes the only serious compiler, but still  :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second one give to you a single string, for your code is worng, you have to use `string.Format` method, so it is has a better performance than first one.

```
String S2 = string.Format("The {0} is made of {1} and is at {2} % durability.", Item.Name, Item.Property, Item.Durability);
```

The first one will generate a lot of strings and do the concatenation operation between `+` operator.

If you have a concatenation inside a loop, the recomentation is to use [`StringBuilder`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2012/08/12/performance-tips-system-text-stringbuilder-and-string-concat.aspx) class.

Take a look at this post: [Most efficient way to concatenate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you correct your second example to use `String.Format`, they should produce the exact same result, yes.

I personally prefer using `String.Format` because it gives me more control. Also, I've always assumed it might be more efficient, although I've done no testing to verify that.

Comment: And don't forget it calls ToString() for you so conversions to string are done automatically.