# Can't enumerate dictionary keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Dictionary<string,string> contactList = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Text = "My Telephone Directory";
    }

    private void txtAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = txtName.Text;
        String teleNo = txtTelephone.Text;

        contactList.Add(name,teleNo);
        txtContactList.Text = "Added " + name;
    }

    private void txtClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtContactList.Text = " ";
    }

    private void txtList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String contactLists="";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in contactList)
        {

            contactLists += "Name: " + contactList.Keys.ToString()+ " Phone No: " + contactList.Values + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        txtContactList.Text = contactLists;
    }

    private void txtSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String contactLists = "";


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in contactList)
        {

            contactLists += "Name: " + contactList.Keys.ToString() + " Phone No: " + contactList.Values + Environment.NewLine;

            if (contactList.Keys.ToString() == txtName.Text)
            {

                contactLists += "Name: " + contactList.Keys.ToString() + " Phone No: " + contactList.Values.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            txtContactList.Text = contactLists;

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    }

}
```

I cant enumerate the dictionary, see the txtList_Click eventhandler.

If I do what im doing, I get System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.String] Phone No: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.String].

If I do contactList.Key like im supposed to I get System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Comment: use ``kvp.Key`` and ``kvp.Value`` in foreach  loop

Comment: `contactList.Keys.ToString()` evaluates to a string containing the *type* (you are asking for a "string" to represent a collection).

Answer (score 1):

**Iterating the Dictionary and building the `contactLists` string**

To iterate the `Dictionary` and build up a string, just use the `KeyValuePair` variable (`kvp`) that you've assigned in the `foreach`:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in contactList)
 {
        contactLists += "Name: " + kvp.Key 
                     + " Phone No: " + kvp.Value + Environment.NewLine;
        ...
```

However, concatenating the string `contactLists` in a loop [is inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/whats-the-best-string-concatenation-method-using-c). `StringBuilder` would help here, or, instead of the loop, you can simply project out each key value pair "string" with a Linq Select, and then `Join` them.

```
var contactLists = 
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        contactList.Select(cl => string.Format("Name: {0} Phone No: {1}",
                           cl.Key, cl.Value)));
```

**Re searching the dictionary**

One of the benefits of using a Dictionary (or HashSet) is that it offers indexed / keyed lookups, so you don't need to iterate the full collection to find an element by manual comparison of keys. So if you've keyed phone numbers by the person's name, this would be a more typical usage:

```
 var searchPhone = contactList[txtName.Text];
```

To make this more robust, you'd want to check if the key exists first, e.g. with `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`:

```
 string searchPhone;
 if (contactList.TryGetValue(text.Name, out searchPhone))
     ... found, use searchPhone
 else
    ... not found
```

Comment: Such a simple mistake, and thanks for your other feedback! Appreciate it alot thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `ToString()` methods on the collection objects rather then the specific key and value pair. Try this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in contactList)
{
    contactLists += "Name: " + kvp.Key + " Phone No: " + kvp.Value + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Saw my mistake now haha.