# What does $ mean before a string?

Tags: c#, string

I was going to use verbatim string but I mistakenly typed `$` instead of `@`.

But the compiler didn't give me any error and compiled successfully.

I want to know what it is and what it does. I searched for it but I couldn't find anything.

However, it is not like a verbatim string because I can't write:

```
string str = $"text\";
```

What does the `$` character in front of a string mean in C#?

```
string str = $"text";
```

I'm using Visual studio 2015 CTP.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

`$` is short-hand for `String.Format` and is used with string interpolations, which is a new feature of C# 6. As used in your case, it does nothing, just as `string.Format()` would do nothing.

It is comes into its own when used to build strings with reference to other values. What previously had to be written as:

```
var anInt = 1;
var aBool = true;
var aString = "3";
var formated = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", anInt, aBool, aString);
```

Now becomes:

```
var anInt = 1;
var aBool = true;
var aString = "3";
var formated = $"{anInt},{aBool},{aString}";
```

There's also an alternative - less well known - form of string interpolation using `$@`  (the order of the two symbols is important). It allows the features of a `@""` string to be mixed with `$""` to support string interpolations without the need for `\\` throughout your string. So the following two lines:

```
var someDir = "a";
Console.WriteLine($@"c:\{someDir}\b\c");
```

will output:

```
c:\a\b\c
```

Comment: Note that it's not really using String.Format, but is a compiler-based feature, not a runtime one.

Comment: Minor note that I learned today, if you use `$@`, then you're forced to escape the `"` character by using `""`. This is not the case when you only use `$`.

Comment: @Flater That has nothing to do with the $ symbol though. That's the same behavior as it was before the $ symbol existed.

Comment: To your point about the order of the verbatim (@) and interpolation ($) symbol ordering being important, this is being corrected in C# 8 so that the ordering will no longer matter. See: http://www.devsanon.com/uncategorized/c-8-is-fixing-interpolated-verbatim-strings/

Comment: Very nice explanation. Always a thumb up for such a thorough approach (also regarding simple subjects)

Answer (score 44):

It creates an [interpolated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation).

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx)

> Used to construct strings. An interpolated string expression looks
>   like a template string that contains expressions. An interpolated
>   string expression creates a string by replacing the contained
>   expressions with the ToString represenations of the expressions’
>   results.

ex :

```
 var name = "Sam";
 var msg = $"hello, {name}";

 Console.WriteLine(msg); // hello, Sam
```

You can use expressions within the interpolated string

```
 var msg = $"hello, {name.ToLower()}";
 Console.WriteLine(msg); // hello, sam
```

The nice thing about it is that you don't need to worry about the order of parameters as you do with `String.Format`.

```
  var s = String.Format("{0},{1},{2}...{88}",p0,p1,..,p88);
```

Now if you want to remove some parameters you have to go and  update all the counts, which is not the case anymore.

Note that the good old `string.format` is still relevant if you want to specify cultural info in your [formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Note that you could probably still use `$` and specify culture info if you convert your data to string inside of the `$` expression using the correct culture, e.g., `{somevar.ToString(...,[Insert culture info here])}`.

Answer (score 22):

**Example Code**

```
public class Person {
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
}

// Instantiate Person
var person = new Person { firstName = "Albert", lastName = "Einstein" };

// We can print fullname of the above person as follows
Console.WriteLine("Full-Name - " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
Console.WriteLine("Full-Name - {0} {1}", person.firstName, person.lastName);
Console.WriteLine($"Full-Name - {person.firstName} {person.lastName}");
```

**Output**

```
Full-Name - Albert Einstein
Full-Name - Albert Einstein
Full-Name - Albert Einstein
```

---

It is **Interpolated Strings**. You can use an interpolated string anywhere you can use a string literal. When running your program would execute the code with the interpolated string literal, the code computes a new string literal by evaluating the interpolation expressions. This computation occurs each time the code with the interpolated string executes.

Following example produces a string value where all the string interpolation values have been computed. It is the final result and has type string. All occurrences of double curly braces `(“{{“ and “}}”)` are converted to a single curly brace.

```
string text = "World";
var message = $"Hello, {text}";
```

After executing above 2 lines, variable `message` contains "Hello, World".

```
Console.WriteLine(message); // Prints Hello, World
```

Reference - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Nice answer. Not quite anywhere that you can use a string literal though — you cannot use it when declaring a constant string (const string constantString = $"Default is {someValue}" is not supported).

Answer (score 11):

Note that you can also **combine** the two, which is pretty cool (although it looks a bit odd):

```
// simple interpolated verbatim string
WriteLine($@"Path ""C:\Windows\{file}"" not found.");
```

Comment: If just you could decide the order in which you typed `$@` or `@$`. Unfortunately it can only be `$@`

Comment: @Bauss This makes sense. `@` defines how to represent the string literal. `$` is a shortcut for `string.Format`. Think of it as `$(@"");`

Comment: It's not really a shortcut for `string.Format`. It's sugary for presenting a value that gets parsed to a `string.Format`, so it partially makes sense, but not entirely.

Comment: I'm just saying `$` is basically an implied function call whereas `@` is part of the literal, just like the `m` in a decimal literal. That's why there's only one logical order.

Comment: I know this was mostly just here to demonstrate `$`, but for the sake of maximum compatibility and not hard coding whether the directory separator is '/' or '\', and also avoiding the inevitable screwup causing a double slash or missing slash where there should have been one, I recommend using `Path.Combine()` instead of using string concatenations when working with directories and files.

Comment: @jrh This is just console output. Hence no compatibility issues. Besides, you said it, this is just for demonstration. We know that `Path.Combine` is better.

Comment: @marsze Have to say it just in case (I'm working on a codebase where the author used nothing but string concatenations instead of `Path.Combine()`).

Answer (score 11):

Cool feature. I just want to point out the emphasis on why this is better than string.format if it is not apparent to some people.

I read someone saying order string.format to "{0} {1} {2}" to match the parameters. You are not forced to order "{0} {1} {2}" in string.format, you can also do "{2} {0} {1}". However, if you have a lot of parameters, like 20, you really want to sequence the string to "{0} {1} {2} ... {19}". If it is a shuffled mess, you will have a hard time lining up your parameters.

With $, you can add parameter inline without counting your parameters. This makes the code much easier to read and maintain.

The downside of $ is, you cannot repeat the parameter in the string easily, you have to type it. For example, if you are tired of typing System.Environment.NewLine, you can do string.format("...{0}...{0}...{0}", System.Environment.NewLine), but, in $, you have to repeat it. You cannot do $"{0}" and pass it to string.format because $"{0}" returns "0".

On the side note, I have read a comment in another duplicated tpoic. I couldn't comment, so, here it is. He said that

```
string msg = n + " sheep, " + m + " chickens";
```

creates more than one string objects. This is not true actually. If you do this in a single line, it only creates one string and placed in the string cache.

```
1) string + string + string + string;
2) string.format()
3) stringBuilder.ToString()
4) $""
```

All of them return a string and only creates one value in the cache.

On the other hand:

```
string+= string2;
string+= string2;
string+= string2;
string+= string2;
```

Creates 4 different values in the cache because there are 4 ";".

Thus, it will be easier to write code like the following, but you would create five interpolated string as Carlos Muñoz corrected:

```
string msg = $"Hello this is {myName}, " +
  $"My phone number {myPhone}, " +
  $"My email {myEmail}, " +
  $"My address {myAddress}, and " +
  $"My preference {myPreference}.";
```

This creates one single string in the cache while you have very easy to read code. I am not sure about the performance, but, I am sure MS will optimize it if not already doing it.

Comment: Your last example is wrong: Actually you are crating two strings: One from the interpolated string and other from the rest of the strings. Notice that only the one with {myName} is interpolated, the others don't work as expected.

Comment: And if you prepend $ to the 5 strings it then creates 5 interpolated strings each with their own `String.Format()` and then concatenated at runtime with `String.Concat`. So it is better that you don't split it into multiple lines

Comment: You are right @Carlos Muñoz, I have corrected it. Thanks for catching the mistake.

Answer (score 7):

It signifies string interpolation.

It will protect you because it is adding compilation time protection on the string evaluation.

You will no longer get an exception with `string.Format("{0}{1}",secondParamIsMissing)`

Answer (score 7):

It is more convenient than string.Format and you can use intellisense here too.

[image]

And here is my test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void StringMethodsTest_DollarSign()
{
    string name = "Forrest";
    string surname = "Gump";
    int year = 3; 
    string sDollarSign = $"My name is {name} {surname} and once I run more than {year} years."; 
    string expectedResult = "My name is Forrest Gump and once I run more than 3 years."; 
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, sDollarSign);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The following example highlights various advantages of using interpolated strings over `string.Format()` as far as cleanliness and readability goes.  It also shows that code within `{}` gets evaluated like any other function argument, just as it would if `string.Format()` we're being called.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var name = "Horace";
      var age = 34;
      // replaces {name} with the value of name, "Horace"
      var s1 = $"He asked, \"Is your name {name}?\", but didn't wait for a reply.";
      Console.WriteLine(s1);

      // as age is an integer, we can use ":D3" to denote that
      // it should have leading zeroes and be 3 characters long
      // see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros
      //
      // (age == 1 ? "" : "s") uses the ternary operator to 
      // decide the value used in the placeholder, the same 
      // as if it had been placed as an argument of string.Format
      //
      // finally, it shows that you can actually have quoted strings within strings
      // e.g. $"outer { "inner" } string"
      var s2 = $"{name} is {age:D3} year{(age == 1 ? "" : "s")} old.";
      Console.WriteLine(s2); 
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       He asked, "Is your name Horace?", but didn't wait for a reply.
//       Horace is 034 years old.
```

Answer (score 7):

$ syntax is nice, but with one downside.

If you need something like a string template, that is declared on the class level as field...well in one place as it should be.

Then you have to declare the variables on the same level...which is not really cool.

It is much nicer to use the string.Format syntax for this kind of things

```
class Example1_StringFormat {
 string template = $"{0} - {1}";

 public string FormatExample1() {
   string some1 = "someone";
   return string.Format(template, some1, "inplacesomethingelse");
 }

 public string FormatExample2() {
   string some2 = "someoneelse";
   string thing2 = "somethingelse";
   return string.Format(template, some2, thing2);
 }
}
```

The use of globals is not really ok and besides that - it does not work with globals either

```
 static class Example2_Format {
 //must have declaration in same scope
 static string some = "";
 static string thing = "";
 static string template = $"{some} - {thing}";

//This returns " - " and not "someone - something" as you would maybe 
//expect
 public static string FormatExample1() {
   some = "someone";
   thing = "something";
   return template;
 }

//This returns " - " and not "someoneelse- somethingelse" as you would 
//maybe expect
 public static string FormatExample2() {
   some = "someoneelse";
   thing = "somethingelse";
   return template;
 }
}
```

Comment: This answer is important as it points out that the interpolation occurs when you "call" the $string, not when you declare it.

Comment: You're right about the anti-pattern of declaring your interpolation variables at the class scope, however if those variables *already belong* as class properties, this pattern works well.

Comment: @dx_over_dt You are wrong. Interpolated strings are evaluated at the time they are declared. That's why the sample code makes no sense. It will also not compile.

Comment: @NineBerry You are correct both about interpolated strings are evaluated at the time they are declared and about Example_$Format does not compile and about sample code makes not sense :) I have  corrected the sample to explain it better.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how it works, but you can also use it to tab your values !

Example :

```
Console.WriteLine($"I can tab like {"this !", 5}.");
```

Of course, you can replace "this !" with any variable or anything meaningful, just as you can also change the tab.

Comment: yes you can also format the string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Answer (score 1):

the $ sign in the string is for definition of interpolation string that is a feature in C# to interpolate the string is a "true string" that might contain interpolated expressions

for further information this is the source of the answer and example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated