# Prompt the user to enter time in seconds, then display it in minutes and seconds

Tags: c#, time

**//what I have done so far**

```
int seconds, minutes;

Console.Write("Seconds: ");
seconds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is there a problem you're having? Looks like you just need it to write it to the console. Not sure what you're going for with the % 60 though.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad if the user enters 65 seconds, the integer division will give 1 minute.  The remainder (5) is assigned back to seconds using modulo division.

Comment: I agree, what is the issue here?  Just writing two numbers out to the console?

Comment: @Amy Ah that makes sense. I was confused trying to figure out what the point of showing the seconds was when that's what the user entered. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: I'm still a rookie here, this a class question "How write a program to prompt the user to to enter to enter time in seconds. The program then displays it in minutes and seconds" . Which I'm just stuck on figure out how answer this question.

Comment: We asked because it seemed like the question was already answered. You just needed to put in `Console.WriteLine("Minutes {0} Seconds {1}", minutes, seconds)` or something like that (there are lots of ways you could write this line).

Comment: please edit your question to state why you are asking, and state what the problem is and the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you just need to output the result to the console, just before the `ReadLine`:

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of seconds: ");
int totalSeconds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

// You're missing this line:
Console.WriteLine($"{totalSeconds} seconds = {minutes} minutes and {seconds} seconds");

Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Also, just so you know, there is a `System.TimeSpan` class that will do these calculations for you. You can create it using the static method `FromSeconds()` (there are others, like `FromDays`, `FromHours`, `FromMinutes`, etc), and then you can access properties like `TotalSeconds` or `Seconds`:

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of seconds: ");
int totalSeconds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var result = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);
Console.WriteLine(
    $"{result.TotalSeconds} seconds = {result.Minutes} minutes and {result.Seconds} seconds");

Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future I recommend trying Google for something simple like this.

```
Console.WriteLine(minutes + " minutes & " + seconds + " seconds");
```

Comment: New & Easier: [`Console.WriteLine($"{minutes} minutes & {seconds} seconds");`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014869/what-does-mean-before-a-string).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I didn't notice you posted an answer till after I put mine up. I kept it simple since OP is a beginner. When I started I never knew about the "$" & "{var}" practice and I learned using the "+" or ".." to add together for console output.

Answer (score 0):

Rufus L answer was accurate bu just a little warning when using `int totalSeconds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`. The user can enter characters and your console application will crash.

You can add try catch bloc to prevent this like so:

```
try {
    int totalSeconds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (FormatException) {
    Console.WriteLine("The entered number is invalid.");
}
```

There are better ways to do that with loops to allow the user to type again.
Check out the [Int.TryParse(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) which return a boolean based on if the parse was successful or not.