# Distinct method does not work Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I get randomly similar data
me tried to merge different ones in the first stage but Different function does not work,

```
    var turler= (from x in db.bird_table_ad
                join e in db.kus_resim on x.tr_x equals e.kus_tur
                where x.aile == item 

                select new GozlemTurleri
                {
                    id = x.id,
                    kod = x.kod,
                    tr_x = x.tr_x,
                    en_x = x.en_x,
                    lt_x = x.lt_x,

                    turfotourl="image_resize.phpad="+e.altDIR+"/"+e.resim+"&yon="+(e.galeri=="fg"?"2":"HD2"),
                    aile = x.aile,
                    gfoto = x.gfoto

                }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: did you try to remove duplicate

Comment: How did I not understand

Comment: did't you try to do with grouping?

Comment: did you try to remove duplicate using specific column? like "id"

Comment: @ZaferKırık distinct makes it unique according to a given value But I don't think this is the right field for your set :)

Comment: @ZaferKırık, where u apply distinct on `id` or `kod` or any other fields?

Comment: take a look at [Distinct() with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31014869/4977870)

Comment: GroupBy(f=>f.tr_x).ToList();

this not work

Comment: tList = turler.GroupBy(f => new { b=f.tr_x,a=f.id } ).Select(f =>f.First()).ToList();
this code ;
brings the first line after grouping

Comment: I need you to query the column


tList = turler.GroupBy(f => new { b=f.tr_x,a=f.id } ).Select(f =>f.Max(g=>g.mycolum)).ToList();

Comment: EXAMPLE SQL CODE 

SELECT id, MAX(rev)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id

EF CODE ????

Answer (score 1):

If you try to get distinct record with regarding to `tr_x` from database then you can use `GroupBy` in entity framework.

So your code will be.

```
.GroupBy(x => x.tr_x).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Instead of

```
.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: .GroupBy(x => x.tr_x).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

did worked for me

How can I make the selection randomly

select(x=>x.random) ??

Comment: could u plz explain why you need random selection?

Comment: So i can get easily what you want :)

Comment: You stated in your question that you need `randomly similar data` could u plz explain what this mean?

Comment: tList = turler.GroupBy(f => new { b=f.tr_x,a=f.id } ).Select(f =>f.First()).ToList(); this code ; brings the first line after grouping


I need you to query the column tList = turler.GroupBy(f => new { b=f.tr_x,a=f.id } ).Select(f =>f.Max(g=>g.mycolum)).ToList();

Comment: so your query in above comment works or not? means `tList = turler.GroupBy(f => new { b=f.tr_x,a=f.id } ).Select(f =>f.Max(g=>g.mycolum)).ToList(); `

Comment: GroupBy(f => new { b=f.tr_x,a=f.id } ).Select(f =>f.First()).ToList();

this query works correctly but  this code
brings the group first element 
I need to get the most from the HITI column for element;;;

.Select(f =>f.Max(g=>g.hiti))

Comment: `I need to get the most from the HITI column` <= means you need to get those element that have max value of hiti column after grouping, right?

Comment: Yes,  not first- max HITI colum

like this
EXAMPLE SQL CODE SELECT id, MAX(rev) FROM YourTable GROUP BY id EF CODE ???? –

Comment: try this => `.GroupBy(f => new { b = f.tr_x, a = f.id }).Select(x => new { a = x.Key.a, b = x.Key.b, hiti = x.Max(y => y.hiti) }).ToList();`

Comment: **OR** try this => `.GroupBy(f => new { b = f.tr_x, a = f.id }).Select(x => new { a = x.Key.a, b = x.Key.b, hiti = x.Select(y => y.hiti).Max() }).ToList();`

Comment: If my answer was able to solve your problem then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green, otherwise let me know if you faced any problem :)