# return $"({x},{y})"; in c# Can you explain what is $ doing there?

Tags: c#

Here is the code

```
class Coords {

 public int x, y;

 public Coords() {
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
 }

 public override string ToString() {
  return $ "({x},{y})";
  }
}
```

Can you explain what is `$` doing there?
Also, I tried to run it but it showed a compilation error.

Comment: return  $"({x},{y})";

Comment: check for syntax error --> `,`

Comment: [$ - string interpolation - C# Reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Regarding the compilation error: We need to know your version of Visual Studio and project setting. When you have old version of Visual Studio (2013 and before), or you have set old C# language (C# 5 or less), this code will not compile. To change C# version setting see [this link](https://dailydotnettips.com/choosing-the-c-language-latest-version-minor-release-in-visual-studio-2017/).

Answer (score 1):

For your first question.

> Can you explain what is $ doing there?

**Ans:**

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain interpolated expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a result string, items with interpolated expressions are replaced by the string representations of the expression results. This feature is available in C# 6 and later versions of the language.

You can read more about interpolation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

For your second question.

> I tried to run it but it showed a compilation error.

**Ans:**

Remove the space from here

```
return $ "({x},{y})"
        ^
```

So it becomes

```
return $"({x},{y})";
```

If you are using c# version below than 6 then this will be same as interpolation.

```
return string.Format("({0},{1})", x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is named string interpolation

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"({x},{y})";
}
```

This is the same

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a string interpolation operator.
[$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

It allows you to insert C# expressions inside a string block.
The problem with your code seems to be the unnecessary space between the $ operator and your string.

Answer (score 0):

its not available in C# 5 or lower for your info

Answer (score 0):

$ is short-hand for String.Format and is used with string interpolations, which is a new feature of C# 6. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014869/what-does-mean-before-a-string)

In your case it's the same as

> string.Format("({0},{1})", x, y);

But no spaces between $ and " is allowed. So you should use

> $"({x},{y})" (no space after $)