# How to take n part of String using Split() method in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have string `str = "Join Smith hate meat"`.

I want to get `JoinSmith` from this `str`.

I tried code:

```
private static string GetFirstWord(string str)
{
    return str.Split(' ').Take(2).ToString();
}
```

This code not working for me.

I tried: `return str.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault` it get only first part of string `Join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fancy combination:

```
var result = string.Join(String.Empty, str.Split(' ').Take(2));
```

Takes the first two words, joins them into one string.

Or:

```
var result = string.Concat(str.Split(' ').Take(2));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
string result = string.Concat(str.Split(' ').Take(2)); // "JoinSmith"
```

Comment: SO is not a competition between the users. I think it should be a competition between the answers. So that someone who searches for a solution gets the best by choosing the answer with the most votes.  And in this case `string.Concat` should be used over `strign.Join` http://stackoverflow.com/a/12257751/1315444

Comment: I up-vote your answer. I think @user3185569 reply before your answer and it working. After, he was updated the answer.

Comment: @VănLộc both answers are working. `string.Concat()` is the better solution in this case (performance and readability). By copying my answer into his, my answer got obsolete. Imo that's not how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Something a little different

```
var result = new string(TakeAllUntilSecondSpace(str).ToArray());
```

Yield the characters you want... sometimes this is a good way if you need a lot of control that standard methods don't provide.

```
private IEnumerable<char> TakeAllUntilSecondSpace(string s)
{
    var spaceEncountered = false;
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            if (spaceEncountered) yield break;
            spaceEncountered = true;
        } else yield return c;
    }
}
```