# How to make startInfo.Arguments accept multiple commands?

Tags: c#, powershell

Hi I'm trying to run this program

```
string exeDir = "C:\\svn\\Services\\trunk\\In4m\\Services.In4m.MachineStatusServices\\Scripts\\aws-newAPIKey";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
string powershellcommands = "echo 'Hi5'; echo '66' ";
startInfo.Arguments = powershellcommands;
//startInfo.WorkingDirectory = exeDir;


Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
string awsApiKey=String.Empty;
while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    awsApiKey = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

    // do something with line
}
Console.WriteLine(awsApiKey);
process.WaitForExit();
```

When I run this.. the echo Hi5 gets replaced by 66. How to make arguments accept multiple parameters without using a file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to concatenate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-strings)

Comment: Please be careful of using reading the standard output synchronously.  It can cause locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running both commands in your argument, your while loop is overwriting `awsApiKey`.

try:

```
awsApiKey += process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

Comment: it shows hiecho66 now.. how to execute the second line without echo popping up

Comment: @the_coder_in_me Double check your argument string, you probably removed or misplaced your semicolon.