# Next text input on different line

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, textbox

I have textbox that I use for diagnostic purposes. The code behind is really simple:

XAML:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="640,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="280" Width="840" Name="txtDiagnostic" IsHitTestVisible="True" />
```

C#:

```
private void AddMessage(string message)
{
    txtDiagnostic.Text += (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") + " " + message);
}
```

How can I define that each new input is on a different line? Because right now all errors are in just 1 long line.

> 14:15:00 Error 1 14:16:00 Error 2 14:17:00 Error 3

Instead of readable with line breaks between each error like this example:

> 14:15:00 Error 1
>   14:16:00 Error 2
>   14:17:00 Error 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add an [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) at the end of each string

```
txtDiagnostic.Text += (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") + " " + message) + Environment.NewLine;
```

and make sure that the textbox is [capable of multiline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-multiline-textbox-control)

XAML:

```
<TextBox
  Name="tbMultiLine"
  TextWrapping="Wrap"
  AcceptsReturn="True"                    <-- IMPORTANT
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"   <-- IMPORTANT
>
```

EDIT: As to respond to the usual [string concatination debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-strings) you can of course use [string.Concat()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
String.Concat(txtDiagnostic.Text,DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") , " " , "ERROR....." , Environment.NewLine);
```

It will be faster. Here is a benchmark code for LINQPad with a 1000 lines:

```
void Main()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    string text = "";
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        //text += (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") + " " + "ERROR.....") + Environment.NewLine;
        String.Concat(text,DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") , " " , "ERROR....." , Environment.NewLine);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("ELAPSED: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

}
```

Output:

> `+` concatentation took (on my machine) 16 msek
>   `Concat` needed 10 msek

Choose yourself, you should know how many error messages you would like to "inform" the user with ;)

Disclaimer: 1000 lines is a very bad benchmark, but I chose it here to fit the use case at hand. Reading more than a 1000 (or even a 1000) lines of error messages is not a software I would like to use. If you start concatenating larger sets of lines (x > 1000) then you really should use the `StringBuilder` as is also mentioned in the *string concatenation debate* Link that I provided.

Comment: By the way, you should consider using `string.Concat()` or a `StringBuilder` instead of `+` when putting strings together.

Comment: Which benefits does that have?

Comment: @Atlasmaybe not necessarily. It depends on the amount. Using a `StringBuilder` looks like overhead to me here. `Concat` would be probably the fastes way, but the difference might be negligable depending on the amount of lines OP wants to show

Comment: @Belekz what is the guessed maximum amount of lines that you would like to display?

Comment: If you repeat this task quite often of creating this new string you set together , you get a huge performance improvement with using a `StringBuilder` instead of using the *default* string set together thingy.

Comment: At this moment I would say 15 lines, because it's a very small application, but I'll use this technique again in next applications for sure.

Comment: @Belekz, then you should really consider using a `StringBuilder`. Also, if you want to debug your application, you could also use `Debug.WriteLine()` or `Trace.WriteLine()`

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of `Environment.NewLine` from the source code:

The implementation in .NET 4.6.1: [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs#63a04833d43dd9d3)

```
/*===================================NewLine====================================
**Action: A property which returns the appropriate newline string for the given
**        platform.
**Returns: \r\n on Win32.
**Arguments: None.
**Exceptions: None.
==============================================================================*/
public static String NewLine {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        return "\r\n";
    }
}
```

So you could go with `\r\n` as your last two digits of the `string` as output text and the result is the exact same as Mong Zhu's answer, since `Environment.NewLine` is it's implementation.

```
txtDiagnostic.Text += (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") + " " + message + "\r\n");
```

---

It depends on the platform if you either use `\n` or `\r\n`. On Windows it is actually `\r\n`.

From MSDN:

> A string containing "\r\n" for
>   non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also AppendText():

```
this.txtTest.AppendText("blablabla" + Environment.NewLine);
```