# Replace middle letters with uppercase

Tags: c#, string

There is the following code, it has a function that finds the letters in word in its middle (1 or 2 characters) and makes them capital, and then outputs.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test("Rofl"));
        Console.WriteLine(test("Camel"));
        Console.WriteLine(test("R"));
    }

    public static String test(string value) {
        return value.Length % 2 == 0 
            ? value.Substring(value.Length / 2 - 1, 2).ToUpper()
            : value.Substring(value.Length / 2, 1).ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Tell me, please, how do I make it so that the word was completely derived, but the letters from the middle were completely replaced by capital letters?

It is necessary that it be so:

```
ROFl
CaMel
R
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?
Not the cleanest of ways.

```
public static string test(string value)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
    var array = value.ToCharArray();
    if (value.Length % 2 == 0)
    {
        array[value.Length / 2 - 1] = Char.ToUpper(array[value.Length / 2 - 1]);
        array[value.Length / 2] = Char.ToUpper(array[value.Length / 2]);
    }
    else
    {
        array[value.Length / 2] = Char.ToUpper(value[value.Length / 2]);
    }
    return new string(array);
}
```

Comment: Watch out for dividing by 0. Currently empty string will throw exception.

Comment: This works, but note that it performs two allocations, first in `ToCharArray`, then in `new string`.

Comment: @V0ldek String builder is not always faster it has been pointed out recently to me. Nor that more memory efficient for small strings. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-strings#comment93328343_12257751. `Also check this` -> https://www.meziantou.net/performance-string-concatenation-vs-string-format-vs-interpolated-string.htm

Comment: @panoskarajohn It does put less pressure on the garbage collector, but it only comes in play if this code is on a hot path. Optimisation should always come as a result of profiling an issue, so I'm just pointing out that there's room for improvement, if it's needed. You'd probably get the most efficiency out of the new `string.Create` that takes a `SpanAction`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the transformation with the LINQ `Select` overload that works on pairs element-index.

```cs
public string MiddleLettersToUpper(string s)
{
    IEnumerable<char> transformed;
    if (s.Length % 2 == 0)
    {
        transformed = s.Select((c, i) => 
            i == s.Length / 2 || i == s.Length / 2 - 1 ? char.ToUpper(c) : c);
    }
    else
    {
        transformed = s.Select((c, i) => 
            i == s.Length / 2 ? char.ToUpper(c) : c);
    }

    return string.Concat(transformed);
}
```

It's pretty performant, because `string.Concat` uses a `StringBuilder` underneath, so you only do one pass through the string and allocate one string for the result.

DISCLAIMER: This code doesn't care about the culture when using `ToUpper`, so it's not suitable for production (there's also no argument validation, but that's obvious).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular expression:

```
    public static string test(string value)
    {
        value = value ?? string.Empty;
        int half = value.Length % 2 == 0 ? (value.Length / 2) - 1: (value.Length / 2);
        Regex r = new Regex("(?<=^.{"+ half + "})[a-zA-Z]{1,2}(?=.{"+ half + "}$)");
        var match = r.Match(value);
        if (match != null)
        {
            var result = r.Replace(value, match.ToString().ToUpper());
            return result;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

First we found the half count of letters (the count of letter in the bigging and the end not to uppaer)

Regular expression explains:

find start of a line (^) + any charecter (.) half count ({half}) but don't take them (Positive precedes Lookahead ?<=)

then find one or two charecters ({1,2}) in abc ([a-zA-Z]) - this is the match

and on the end find any charecter (.) half count ({half}) + end of a line ($) but again don't take them (Positive follows Lookahead ?=).

You can test this regex here : [regex101](https://regex101.com/)