# string.Format and the word "Password"

Tags: c#, string

Using C#, I need to build a connection string from a few AppSettings. If I do this:

```
Connection = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1);User Id={2};Password={3};",
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CartServer"),
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CartDatabase"),
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CartUserName"),
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CartPassword"));
```

I get an invalid format string exception. I narrowed it down to the "Password=" part of the format string (ie, "Passwork=" works). There's an easy enough work-around:

```
Connection = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1);User Id={2};{3}={4};",
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CartServer"),
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CartDatabase"),
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CartUserName"),
  "Password",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CartPassword")); // Lame!!!
```

But what's the real story with the "Password"? I checked MSDN and a few other sites but came up empty. Oh, if it matters, this is a WCF service.

Comment: Is there a small possibility that your second example is not exactly how it's in your original source?

Comment: Yes there is a strong possibility!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is the {1) in the format string; it should be {1} (you have closed the brace with a parenthesis)

This is causing your FormatException because your format string is now invalid. Why your second entry works is beyond me though.

**Edit:** I agree with the other Richard that you should consider using a connection string builder object.

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered the `DbConnectionStringBuilder` class (or one of its subtypes)?

Answer (score 3):

Obvious.... your problem is because this: "(".

Why don't you use StringBuider class, is easier :)

Comment: gets my vote,  but I'd like to see how StringBuilder is easier.  string.Format (once you get used to the curly brackets) seems about as easy as easy gets.  I know there are performance advantages to StringBuilders, but I haven't seen anyone say it's easier.

Comment: Yes it was! How embarrassing... In my defense, } and ) look very similar in VS2008's default font.

Comment: @dnord - out of interest, why did it get your vote? He answered last, and specified the wrong parenthesis as being the cause. It's possible I've completely missed something.

Comment: Why this is the accepted answer? last posted, and Richard already has answered it.

Comment: I just switched it, they all show up as '4 hrs ago' and this one was at the top, I assumed it was the 1st answer given.

Comment: Sorry about this change of parenthesis....... 

@Richard- I did answer this question before see your answer. StringBuilder is, for me, the best way to concatenate strings... the best way and the easier. Just because :P And stringbuilder is the performante, but not so much

Answer (score 0):

I just Google'd and I had no idea a "DbConnectionStringBuilder" even existed.  Wow, you learn something new everyday.

Also, for other connection strings, check this site out: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why StringBuilder is better than string.Format?

Please check this [Is String.Format as efficient as StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785/is-string-format-as-efficient-as-stringbuilder) to see why...