# String.Format vs "string" + "string" or StringBuilder?

Tags: .net, performance, stringbuilder, string-concatenation, string.format

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is String.Format as efficient as StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785/is-string-format-as-efficient-as-stringbuilder)
>   [C# String output: format or concat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432/c-string-output-format-or-concat)

What is the performance priority and what should be the conditions to prefer each of the following:

```
String.Format("{0}, {1}", city, state);
```

or

```
city + ", " + state;
```

or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(city);
sb.Append(", ");
sb.Append(state);
sb.ToString();
```

Comment: @Shimmy: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785/is-string-format-as-efficient-as-stringbuilder

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/03/12/performance-quiz-1-of-a-series.aspx

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001218.html

Comment: @Freelancer Jeff Atwood's post is indeed a great one! Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Compiler will optimize as much string `concat` as it can, so for example strings that are just broken up for line break purposes can usually be optimized into a single string literal.
- Concatenation with variables will get compiled into `String.Concat`
- `StringBuilder` can be a lot faster if you're doing several (more than 10 or so I guess) "modifications" to a string but it carries some extra overhead because it allocates more space than you need in its buffer and resizes its internal buffer when it needs to.

I personally use `String.Format` almost all of the time for two reasons:

- It's a lot easier to maintain the format string than rearranging a bunch of variables.
- `String.Format` takes a `IFormatProvider` which is passed to any `IFormattable` types embedded in the string (such as numeric) so that you get appropriate numeric formatting for the specified **culture** and overall just more control over how values are formatted.

For example, since some cultures use a comma as a decimal point you would want to ensure with either `StringBuilder` or `String.Format` that you specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` if you wanted to ensure that numbers were formatted the way you intend.

Two more thing to note...

- `StringBuilder` also has an `AppendFormat` function which gives you the flexibility of `String.Format` without requiring an unnecessary second buffer.
- When using `StringBuilder`, make sure you don't defeat the purpose by concatenating parameters that you pass to `Append`. It's an easy one to miss.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relevant diference. But assuming that String.Format internally uses a StringBuilder (you can see that with the Reflector tool), using directly StringBuilder.Append should be faster.

EDIT: Of course that use "+" operator is the worst option since it creates a new string instance for each string that you are concatenating.

Comment: wrong, according to the link i posted bellow it seems than + is the best way

Comment: @shimmy, There is no StringBuilder in that link. Also, in that test, you only concatenate 3 Strings, the number of strings affects the performance a lot.

Comment: The edit is wrong. The C# compiler will assemble the strings or objects into an array and then invoke String.Concat(). I would expect String.Concat(string[]) to be the most efficient because the implementation can allocate the string to exactly the correct length.