# What is the default way to change a character at a certain index in a C# string?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like:

```
string s = "abc";
```

And I want to change the second character to a 'd' so it will be "adc"
I thought this would work:

```
s[1] = 'd';
```

However I get an error:

```
Property or indexer 'string.this[int] 'cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

How can I accomplish this easy task (without using reasonably complicated substring methods?

Comment: The reason you can't just change the one character, and instead need more complex methods, is because Strings are immutable - there is no way to modify an instance of one, and instead all of their helper methods return new, slightly-modified strings. This at least saves you on the potential confusion of figuring out why one instance of a string changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I set a character at an index in a string in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306568/how-do-i-set-a-character-at-an-index-in-a-string-in-c) and another one [Replacing a char at a given index in string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367119/replacing-a-char-at-a-given-index-in-string)

Comment: Have you checked out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Katana314 ... yes I already expected that reason, but I have a string returned from a base class and in rare occasions I have to change one character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`String` is imutable. You can use `StringBuilder` to mutate a string:

```
var s = "abc";
var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb[1] = 'd';
s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Beat me with 10 seconds `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Error message is clear, [`String.Chars` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a read-only. You can't assing it.

Here how it's defined;

```
public char this[
    int index
] { get; }
```

As you can see, there is no `set` accessor.

You can use [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) and [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) methods for this. Here an example on [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/);

```
string s = "abc";
s = s.Remove(1, 1).Insert(1, "d");
s.Dump(); //adc
```

Remember, `string` is [immutable type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). You can't change them. It can't be modified after it is created. Even if you think you change them, you actually create new strings object.

As an alternative, you can use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.StringBuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which represents mutable strings since [`StringBuilder.Chars` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has get and set accessors.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
sb[1] = 'd';
sb.Dump();  // adc
```

Answer (score 2):

It is **not recommended**, but you can do that using `unsafe` context:

```
fixed (char* pfixed = s)
    pfixed[1] = 'd';
```

Comment: I rather go for a neat solution, still plus 1 since it is a valid answer.

Comment: Sure! This answer is just for info. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. You can't change a string, you can only create a new one. To modify a string like that you should use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.Select`:

```
string s = "abc";
string n = new string(s.Select((c, index) => 
            {
                if (index == 1)
                    return 'd';
                else
                    return c;
            }).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(n);  // adc
```