# What’s the difference between System.String and System.StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between string and StringBuilder in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069416/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c)

What’s the difference between System.String and System.StringBuilder? 
It seems to me that the only difference is that System.StringBuilder does not exist in the latest version of C#.

Comment: Vote to close, not a real question. Your confusion may be in part because it is `System.Text.StringBuilder`.

Comment: do not forget to mark answer as accept if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check my post :[Why to use StringBuilder over string to get better performance](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/02/why-to-user-stringbuilder-over-string.html)