# Struggle with ref string input type - read only - need to write

Tags: c#, string, function, ref

**What I want to do**: create a function that takes a string and a single char as input.
The function then shall "flip" every char according to the input char to a lower
or upper case char.

**My Problem:** I want to do this with a ref string input, therefore the string gets
changed in the function directly without the need to create a new string in the function.

Here is the simplified code:

```
 static void Flip(ref string input)
    {

        input[0] = 'a';

    }
```

**The Problem:** Error message -> Property cannot be assigned to, it is read only.

My Question - how can I change that?

What I COULD do is: input = "whatever", but if I want to index through the different
letters in the string with input[i] and change those, it's not possible!

Since I'm new to the "ref" subject - why is this, and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you invoked Flip function? was it `Flip(yourInputString)` or `Flip(ref yourInputString)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are `immutable` that's why its `indexer is read only` from which you can only read and not write into.

> Indexer for string - **public char this[int index] { get; }**

Instead you should use `StringBuilder` which is `mutable` hence its indexer is not read only and you can do in place edits in object.

> Indexer for stringBuilder - **public char this[int index] { get; set; }**

```
static void Flip(ref StringBuilder input)
{
   input[0] = 'a';
}
```

Refer to this for difference [String vs StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069416/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c-sharp).