# How to check if multiple checkboxes are checked

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

So in my program, i have three checboxes (A, B and C). and I want to save the content of the checkbox the is checked to a text file. I am doing this using if statements as shown below:

```
if (a.IsChecked == true)
{
    res = a.Content.ToString() + " is checked"; 
}
else if (b.IsChecked == true)
{
    res = b.Content.ToString() + " is checked";
}
else if (c.IsChecked == true)
{
    res = c.Content.ToString() + " is checked";
}
```

And here is where i am saving the above values to a string and then later in my code to a text file

```
string test = res;
```

Now this is working for me. So i decided to try to check if multiple checkboxes are being checked. So added the below if statements:

```
else if ((a.IsChecked == true) && (b.IsChecked == true) && (c.IsChecked == true))
{
    res= a.Content.ToString() + " " + b.Content.ToString() + " " + c.Content.ToString()
}
```

but this isn't working with me because in the end res is printed in the text file as a rather than a b c. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Also please note that i already initialized res at the top of my code as string:

```
string res;
```

I am not getting any error when i run my code so i am not sure where my mistake is. any help with this is much much appreciated.

thanks a lot :)

Comment: else if ((a.IsChecked == true) && (b.IsChecked == true) && (c.IsChecked == true))
 if any condition fails it  'res' will be null

Answer (score 1):

Its a good practice to use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) in these cases.
On the other hand, if it is ok to have one line for each CheckBox, you can use the following:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 checkappend(ref sb, a);
 checkappend(ref sb, b);
 checkappend(ref sb, c);
 string res = sb.ToString();
```

in which

```
static void checkappend(ref StringBuilder sb, CheckBox ck)
{
    sb.Append(ck.Content.ToString());
    sb.Append(ck.IsChecked == true ?  "is checked." : " is NOT checked.");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Note that creating a separate class can help you when there are many CheckBoxes in a List. You can simply use

```
   foreach (var ck in listOfCheckBoxes)
       checkappend(ref ck, c);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but can you explain to me what stringbuilder is? :)

Comment: Something similar to ``string``, however, it increases performance. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069416/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c-sharp) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it this way:

```
string res = "";
if (a.IsChecked)
{
    res += a.Content.ToString(); 
}
if (b.IsChecked)
{
    res += b.Content.ToString();
}
if (c.IsChecked)
{
    res += c.Content.ToString();
}
```

or simple

```
string res = $"{(a.IsChecked?a.Content+" ":"")}{(b.IsChecked?b.Content+" ":"")}{(c.IsChecked?c.Content:"")}";
```

Answer (score 0):

That's multiple combinations to check. Simply remove `else` from first code snippet to run all checks one after another. You will get only report from last successful check, to have several reports you have to *accumulate* them somehow (add to a list, combine in multi-line string, etc.).

Here is a simple one-liner (using linq):

```
var result = string.Join(" and ", new[] { a, b, c }.Where(o => o.IsChecked).Select(o => $"{o.Content} is checked"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! :)