# How can print number only 6-digit start from 000000-999999 by C#?

Tags: c#

How can print number only 6-digit start from 000000-999999 by C#

```
string st = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= 999999; i++)
{
    st += i.ToString("000000") + "\n";                
}
MessageBox.Show(st);
```

Comment: You want to print _all_ numbers in one message box?

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: You want random numbers or print sequentially?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what issue you're facing with your code, but you might want to consider using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string`.  Every time you add to a `string` you're actually getting a new instance of the `string` and that many new instances can eat up some memory.  Whereas a StringBuilder will change itself, instead of creating new instances. See [Difference between string and StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069416/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c-sharp)

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 999999; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(i.ToString("000000"));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: this one its work , but take time to print one-by-one

Comment: @Fabio It's clearly explained in my answer and in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069416/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder-in-c-sharp There will be less memory consumption with a performance increase.

Comment: @Fabio how do you even know what OP wants, it’s not clear at all.

Comment: @maccettura, I don't, but I know that OP didn't ask about how to improve performance. And output of OP's code and output of this answer will be exactly same.