# TextBox Memory Consumption

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` which is a list of items wherein each item contains a lot of `TextBox` and `TextBlock` controls. I tried disabling undo steps but the memory consumption is quite high even after adding 10 items in the list. I tried running the memory analysis tool and I could see that TextBoxes are the biggest consumer of memory of around 50 MB.

My XAML is as below

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:GenericButtonConverter x:Key="ButtonConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RawSendListTemplate">
        <ListBoxItem BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3,1,3,1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="52"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0"  Text="ID" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Coral" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Path=CanId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11"   Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxLength="8"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1" />

                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="2"  Text="CHANNEL" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11"  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Coral" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="3"  Text="{Binding Path=Channel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11"  Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxLength="1"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>

                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="4"  Text="Length" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11"  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Coral" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="5"  Text="{Binding Path=Len , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11"  Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold"  MaxLength="1"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>

                <Button     Grid.Column="6"  Content="Send" x:Name="RawSendButton" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SendButtonEnabled}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11"  FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Black"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                            Command="{Binding ButtonClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource ButtonConverter}}"/>

                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="7"  Text="CYCLE" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Coral" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="8"  Text="{Binding Path=CycleTimeMs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SendButtonEnabled}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11"  Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="4"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
                <CheckBox   Grid.Column="9"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=CyclicEnableChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CyclicEnable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"    MinWidth="20" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,40,0"/>

                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="10" Text="DATA" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Coral" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="11" Text="{Binding Path=Byte1}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Byte1Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="2"
                            TextAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="12" Text="{Binding Path=Byte2}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Byte2Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="13" Text="{Binding Path=Byte3}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Byte3Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="14" Text="{Binding Path=Byte4}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Byte4Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="15" Text="{Binding Path=Byte5}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Byte5Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="16" Text="{Binding Path=Byte6}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Byte6Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="17" Text="{Binding Path=Byte7}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Byte7Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
                <TextBox    Grid.Column="18" Text="{Binding Path=Byte8}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Byte8Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="20" FontSize="11" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="SemiBold" MaxLength="2"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False" MaxLines="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>        
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="RawSendList" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Margin="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel.RawMessages}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RawSendListTemplate}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding MyViewModel.SelectedRawMessageItem, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectionMode="Single" Background="OldLace"/>
</Grid>
```

I need some help reducing the memory footprint of the list item.

Function Name   Total CPU (%)   Self CPU (%)    Total CPU (ms)  Self CPU (ms)   Module

- Gazelle.exe (PID: 8516)    100.00 %    0.00 %  29761   0   Gazelle.exe
- [External Code]    99.80 % 23.01 % 29701   6849    50 modules
- Gazelle.App::Main  0.19 %  0.00 %  58  0   Gazelle.exe
- Gazelle.MainWindow::InitializeComponent    0.01 %  0.00 %  2   0   Gazelle.exe

Object Type Count   Size (Bytes)    Inclusive Size (Bytes)  Module

- ListItem 10,464     251,136     573,839,736  PresentationCore.dll
- TextBox  10,008    18,376,324       278,265,656  PresentationFramework.dll
- List   25,098     23,258,200     185,202,668   mscorlib.dll
- TextEditor   10,008     2,175,548      158,375,060   PresentationFramework.dll
- Grid 12,624       12,400,172     151,944,940 PresentationFramework.dll
- ListBoxItem  1,668     1,013,444     128,034,940 PresentationFramework.dll
- TemplateNameScope    25,098      803,136     121,480,864 PresentationFramework.dll
- ScrollViewer 10,015      10,694,204       81,834,452 PresentationFramework.dll
- ContentPresenter 3,387   2,420,780      28,512,660   PresentationFramework.dll
- EventHandler 233,861     10,732,196      25,202,352  mscorlib.dll
- BindingExpression    65,292     24,139,292      24,189,152   PresentationFramework.dll
- Border   13,419       11,634,248      18,898,436 PresentationFramework.dll
- TextBoxView  10,008  11,549,424  18,597,828  PresentationFramework.dll
- HybridDictionary 52,843  7,811,596   18,090,272  System.dll
- ModifiedValue    192,048 4,803,732   16,476,568  WindowsBase.dll
- ScrollBar    20,022  15,381,092  16,358,688  PresentationFramework.dll
- ScrollContentPresenter   10,011  10,158,248  14,169,188  PresentationFramework.dll

[UPDATE]

Adding this in the XAML is making the Application more responsive

```
UndoLimit="0" AcceptsReturn="False"  IsUndoEnabled="False"
```

Now I am wondering where else I could gain some more

Comment: Why?  Memory is cheap.  Are you getting OOM exceptions?  If not, don't worry about it.  Allocation is expensive, so the CLR tends to hold onto any memory allocated. Put down Task Manager and walk away.

Comment: What kind of memory did you measure?

Comment: After adding several items, the Application responsiveness is very slow.

Comment: @WinterS Then you have something else that affects the system performance.

Comment: I measured with Performance and Diagnostics, CPU usage is low, 0.09% but memory spiked.

Comment: @WinterS It's probably those bindings.  You need to look at your C# code and figure out the problem.  I guarantee the problem is not in XAML.

Comment: I suspect its the Bindings too, but I am not able to figure out yet.

Comment: Well, everybody expects it is the bindings because that's all they can look at.  Show us the reports you obtained from a memory profiler instead.

Comment: I've run into problems in the past when displaying many TextBoxes on the screen at once in a Grid, and had two very different solutions to this problem. The first was caused by [updating the `.Text` frequently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8733887/302677), and resolved by setting `IsUndoEnabled="False"` to disable tracking and storing `TextBox.Text` changes. The second solution involved displaying everything as a `TextBlock`, which uses much less memory than a `TextBox`, and changing the template to a `TextBox` when the user goes to edit it (such as clicking on the item).

Comment: You could cut the amount of your xaml clutter by more than half pretty easily, and I forget, but is virtualization a default on ListBox for WPF? If not, you're probably going to want to look at that too at least.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Rachel I also found the same thing, disabling undo makes it a little bit more responsive.

Comment: Slow and uses too much memory are not the same problem.  What problem are you trying to solve?  And you could reduce the amount of syntax with styles.