# using substring properly on a stringbuilder type

Tags: c#

I am building up a string of data using substring. The format of the data I want is

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

So I am building it up as follows

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("1,");
sb.append("2,");
sb.append("3,");
.
.
.
```

The problem I run into is when I want to trim the final `,` before adding the closing `]`.

I could do

```
sb.ToString();
sb.Substring(0, (sb.Length - 1));
sb += "]";
```

But using the += is not very efficient as this creates a new string. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: and what about opening bracket ?

Comment: `var result = string.Concat("[", string.Join(",", someEnumerable), "]");` is a little faster, and much simpler than a `StringBuilder` approach, I've tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to use `-=` on the `StringBuilder`'s [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.length.aspx) since it's writable:

```
sb.Length -= 1; // removes the last char
```

Comment: Wasn't the question about the `+=`?

Comment: @Jodrell: I'm not sure because the title mentions "using substrings properly"  and "The problem I run into is when I want to trim the final , before adding the closing ]".

Comment: This may need a check if `"[]"` is a valid result. Otherwise the opening bracket might get removed.

Comment: @dtb: Of course this needs an additonal check `if(sb.Length>1)sb.Length -= 1;` before appending the final `]`.

Comment: Setting `.Length` copies the contents of StringBuilder buffer to another newly created array, it's not much different than `Substring` approach so definitely not efficient. Try @dtb 's answer.

Comment: @ssg: Only if the buffer is not large enough for the new length. Which is not the case if the length is decreased.

Answer (score 6):

```
var str = "[" + String.Join(", ",Enumerable.Range(1,10)) + "]";
```

Comment: But it's not what OP has asked for since it creates new strings and it's also not clear that OP wants only integers between 1 and 10 even if it's the sample data.

Comment: Thanks for this, I never knew you could do this with link. It would require a re write of my code so i won't use it now, but it is good for the future @L.B

Comment: I like this approach even if it is not particularly performance worthy due to the creation of several strings.

Comment: @WesleySkeen, you can do it in one line without linq of course, just use `String.Format`, as in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Don't add the final `,` if you don't need it:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder().Append('[');
var first = true;
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        sb.Append(',');
    sb.Append(item);
}
sb.Append(']');
var result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This is the most correct suggestion but the wrong code. You have to check for last one, not the first.

Comment: @ssg: I add a comma before each element except for the first one. Why is that wrong?

Comment: @dtb I thought you added comma after, sorry my bad. Then this is the proper answer.

Comment: @dtb this is the right answer. Sorry for my wrong initial interpretation :) +1ed :)

Comment: `string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", collection));` achieves the same in one line.

Comment: @Jodrell: Sure. But it creates a bunch of intermediate strings. That's not bad. Except if you want to avoid them. So I've proposed a solution that avoids any intermediate string.

Comment: @dtd, is that how `String.Join` and `String.Format` are implemented? Its more sophisticated than that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster

Comment: I did a little test, if performance really matters, this method using the `StringBuilder` directly is a little faster. I think this must be because the Join-Format method has to allocate and populate the memory twice. +1

Comment: @dtb, I did a little more testing and found a `Concat` and `Join` combination is actually faster than `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

After a little testing

```
var result = string.Concat("[", string.Join(",", someEnumerable), "]");
```

is both much simpler and faster than a builder approach

---

You could always just do

```
var result = string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", someEnumerable));
```

The sequence can be anything you want, for instance

```
var someEnumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
```

This seems simpler than reinventing the wheel, and avoids intermediate strings.

This does make assumptions about the implementation of `String.Join` but, I think you should assume that its good enough for this purpose.

---

For more information, [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster) does a comparison between `String.Join` and `StringBuilder`.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785/is-string-format-as-efficient-as-stringbuilder) indicates that `String.Format` uses a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Whilst it was not me that downvoted, the code does not work. It should be string.Join(",", someEnumerable));

Comment: Also I do not know if this is creating multiple strings behind the scenes.

Comment: @activwerx, doh, fixed the ommited parameter. You are right, I don't know how `String.Join` is implemented either but, I should assume that its has been provided for a reason.

Comment: Well I've removed the downvote as I think this is a good implementation! :-)

Comment: `Any comments downvoters?` that sounded so audacious when you know it why you were. Editing a wrong answer and then questioning back masks nothing. SO is so transparent. While I was one downvoter, I removed it now.

Comment: @nawfal I can't catch the exceptions unless they are thrown. I grant that the answer as evolved somewhat but, thats the idea, right?

Comment: @Jodrell yes thats alright. The way you phrased it made it look like you're so sure there's nothing wrong with your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an example as a nice clean method:**

```
    public static string WriteValues(int start, int end)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("[");
        for (int index = start; index <= end; index++)
        {
            sb.Append(index).Append(",");
        }
        sb.Length -= 1;
        sb.Append("]");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This does all the work in the StringBuilder and then passes back a single string. Also you can specify the start and end values!