# .ToString() creates a new string from StringBuilder, so why not use string directly?

Tags: c#

I have seen questions related to string builder but was not able to find relevant answer.

My question is "Is it wise to use string builder here? if not how to use it wisely here".

This method is going to run 100000 times. In order to save some memory I used stringbuilder here. but the problem is `.ToString()` method. Anyway I will have to create a string using `.ToString()` method so why not initialize `filename` as  string rather than `StringBuilder`.

```
internal bool isFileExists()
{
    StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Registry\\" + postalCode + ".html");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName.ToString()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

All libraries method use string as a parameter not string builder why?
I think I got a lot of confusion in my concepts.

Comment: using the `StringBuilder` in this instance doesn't seem to add any value, you would typically use it to append values to a buffer then return that string once complete. You may as well just use a single `string` than a `StringBuilder` instance here.

Comment: Why not just use `return System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Registry\\" , postalCode , ".html"));` ?

Comment: @Charlie see SaverioTerracciano's answer for more detail

Comment: There is no reason (Really no reason) to use string builder here. it cant be even wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you are not using string builder. You first make a string by:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Registry\\" + postalCode + ".html"
```

And then feed it to the string builder.

To use StringBuilder correctly:

```
StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder();
fileName.Append(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
fileName.Append("Registry\\");
fileName.Append(postalCode );
fileName.Append(".html");
```

If you make liners to make strings you can just make the string by:

```
string filenamestr = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Registry\\" + postalCode + ".html";
```

In this case you are making a filepath, so it is recommended to use:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Registry\\" , postalCode , ".html");
```

Comment: So I allocate two strings. One to assign string to stringbuilder and one to make a string from stringbuilder.

Comment: using .Append(string str) you still create string str, so the optimization is doubtful

Comment: In this case I would not use a stringbuilder

Comment: @enkryptor Are you sure filename.Append creates a new string. How is it use full then?

Comment: @Charlie if you pass a string literal (e.g. ".html") that string has to be allocated.

Comment: @enkryptor the string is only created once and then added to the StringBuilder, if you'd add it to another string you'd create 2 strings.

Comment: My mistake, when parameter is a constant it is being created once.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually creating 4 `strings` here. 
The first one is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Registry\\"`.
The second one is when you add `+ postalCode` to that string.
The third one when you add `+ ".html"`.
The fourth one when you call `fileName.ToString()`.

If you want to use `StringBuilder`, you should do it like this:

```
StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
fileName.Append("Registry\\");
fileName.Append(".html");
```

As  Hans Kesting kindly reminded me, you are not *really* creating 4 `strings`. The compiler optimizes it to one call to [`String.Concat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx).

Comment: Not quite: `string + string + string` is translated by the compiler into a single call to [String.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx)

Comment: @HansKesting yea thats true, I just wanted to show what would happen without compiler optimizations

Comment: @HansKesting thanks for the correction though, I figured that the compiler would do some kind of optimization, just didn't know exactly what it was.

Answer (score 2):

Given what your code do (check if a file exists), the real bottleneck will not be using a string or a stringbuilder but checking if the file really exists... So I would let the system do the concatenation of string and taking care of performances:

```
internal bool isFileExists()
{
    return System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Registry\\" , postalCode , ".html"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it doesn't make sense to create first a `StringBuilder` and then a `string`.

`Strings` are immutable in C#, and when you need to make changes to them (Replace, Append, etc.) another string is created in the string pool. 
The allocation of such has a cost, and in case of several different operations this cost add up and it becomes really expensive.

`StringBuilder` is an object that can internally change, and is much faster (has a smaller cost) for the upsaid operations, hence it's preferable to use it.

The point in which one is better than the others changes according to the scenario, but as a rule of thumb, if you find yourself changing over and over in the same method the same string, it might be a good idea to use a StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use string.Format. It uses StringBuilder internally.

In your case:

```
    var fileName = string.Format("{0}Registry\\{1}.html", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, postalCode);
```

[Is String.Format as efficient as StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785/is-string-format-as-efficient-as-stringbuilder)

Answer (score 1):

*IO* operations (even `File.Exists`) is more time consuming than `String` creating; you can't avoid `File.Exists` test that's why, IMHO, the *readability* is that matters the most:

1. String *formatting*
2. No *redundant* `if`

Implementation:

```
internal bool isFileExists() {
  return File.Exists(String.Format("{0}Registry\\{1}.html", 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    postalCode));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks weird isFileExists() doesn't use postalCode parameter. Is it just an example or piece of a real code?

I suggest you not to use File.Exists() thousands of times. Make a hashtset with file names and look it up instead.