# Building up strings from variables by neither using + nor StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

Assume we have

```
string one = "1";
string two = "2";
string three = "3";
```

And we want to get the result string

```
result = "1, 2, 3"
```

by building it from the above three variables.

I know I can do it like this

```
result = one + ", " + two + ", " + three;
```

but as far as I understand, then a lot of strings are generated and thrown away again (first `1`, then `1,`, then `1, 2`, then `1, 2,`, then `1, 2, 3`). I know I can use a `StringBuilder` to prevent creating new strings all the time, but this is also not what I am looking for.

In my case, I know from the start how the string will look, I only need to put references of the variables into the result string.

I know I have seen a syntax before (C#). I think it looks a bit like this:

```
result = "{0}, {1}, {2}", one, two, three
```

Questions:

- What is the syntax?
- What is the correct name for putting a string together from pieces when the pattern is known? I assume there is a more specific word than "concatenate". In my understanding, "concatenate" is something you want to do at runtime, when you don't know in the beginning which or how many strings are to be connected.

<s>- Is there a difference in performance or memory usage compared to using a `StringBuilder`?</s> (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/299541/5333340 - it seems `string.Concat` is faster.)

Comment: Maybe you refer to [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You mean String.Join?

Comment: `string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}", 10, 100);`

Comment: I would be careful of assuming that an answer about performance, written in 2008, is still relevant 8 years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What is the syntax?

`var result = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", one, two, three);`

or (C# 6.0 string interpolation, which is just syntactic sugar for `string.Format`)

`var result = $"{one}, {two}, {three}";`

- What is the correct name for putting a string together from pieces when the pattern is known? I assume there is a more specific word than "concatenate". In my understanding, "concatenate" is something you want to do at runtime, when you don't know in the beginning which or how many strings are to be connected.

String formatting or string interpolation.

- Is there a difference in performance or memory usage compared to using a StringBuilder?

[As of .NET 4.0, `string.Format` uses a cached `StringBuilder` internally, so the performance difference is minimal.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27902469/70345) For very large and/or very many strings, using a raw `StringBuilder` will be fastest, but for most cases, `string.Format` will be good enough in terms of performance, and a lot more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the `string.Join` approach. This avoids the redundant inserting of the seperator compared to your required `String.Format`

```
string one = "1";
string two = "2";
string three = "3";
string result = string.Join(", ", one, two, three);
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition to string.join and string.format, you could also use [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx) which looks cleaner than string.format in many scenarios - e.g.

```
result = $"{one}, {two}, {three}";
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are looking for is

```
result = String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", one, two, three);
```